# What is the use of the JavaScript 'bind' method?

Tags: javascript, function, bind

What is the use of `bind()` in JavaScript?

Answer (score 838, accepted):

Bind creates a new function that will force the `this` inside the function to be the parameter passed to `bind()`.

Here's an example that shows how to use `bind` to pass a member method around that has the correct `this`:

```
var myButton = {
  content: 'OK',
  click() {
    console.log(this.content + ' clicked');
  }
};

myButton.click();

var looseClick = myButton.click;
looseClick(); // not bound, 'this' is not myButton - it is the globalThis

var boundClick = myButton.click.bind(myButton);
boundClick(); // bound, 'this' is myButton
```

Which prints out:

```
OK clicked
undefined clicked
OK clicked
```

You can also add extra parameters after the 1st (`this`) parameter and `bind` will pass in those values to the original function. Any additional parameters you later pass to the bound function will be passed in after the bound parameters:

```
// Example showing binding some parameters
var sum = function(a, b) {
  return a + b;
};

var add5 = sum.bind(null, 5);
console.log(add5(10));
```

Which prints out:

```
15
```

Check out [JavaScript Function bind](http://www.javascripture.com/Function#bind) for more info and interactive examples.

Update: ECMAScript 2015 adds support for `=>` functions.  `=>` functions are more compact and do not change the `this` pointer from their defining scope, so you may not need to use `bind()` as often. For example, if you wanted a function on `Button` from the first example to hook up the `click` callback to a DOM event, the following are all valid ways of doing that:

```
var myButton = {
  ... // As above
  hookEvent(element) {
    // Use bind() to ensure 'this' is the 'this' inside click()
    element.addEventListener('click', this.click.bind(this));
  }
};
```

Or:

```
var myButton = {
  ... // As above
  hookEvent(element) {
    // Use a new variable for 'this' since 'this' inside the function
    // will not be the 'this' inside hookEvent()
    var me = this;
    element.addEventListener('click', function() { me.click() });
  }
};
```

Or:

```
var myButton = {
  ... // As above
  hookEvent(element) {
    // => functions do not change 'this', so you can use it directly
    element.addEventListener('click', () => this.click());
  }
};
```

Comment: Excellent explantation, but I'm struggling to find examples where I would want to use the third option you described instead of the first option. Can you describe situations where you felt a need to use the the third option?

Comment: @Darryl - One reason why would be to pass parameters from event handlers. If you have this react code: `var Note = React.createClass({ add: function(text){ ... }, render: function () { return <button onClick={this.add.bind(null, "New Note")}/> } }`, then when the button is clicked, it will pass a parameter text "New Note" to the `add` method.

Comment: is there a way to do function({}.bind) ? im receiving `Uncaught TypeError: (intermediate value)(...)`

Answer (score 372):

The simplest use of `bind()` is to make a function that, no matter
how it is called, is called with a particular `this` value.

```js
x = 9;
const module = {
  x: 81,
  getX: function () {
    return this.x;
  }
};

console.log(module.getX()); // 81, because "this" refers to module

const moduleGetX = module.getX;
console.log(moduleGetX()); // 9, because "this" refers to the global object

// Create a new function with 'this' bound to module:
const boundGetX = moduleGetX.bind(module);
console.log(boundGetX()); // 81, again, "this" refers to module
```

Please refer to this link on MDN Web Docs for more information:

[Function.prototype.bind()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)

Comment: The best introduction to bind() I have ever seen.

Comment: Great answer, since your example does not require knowledge about language features (e.g. `prototype`) that might be new to beginners.

Answer (score 193):

[bind](http://javascriptissexy.com/javascript-apply-call-and-bind-methods-are-essential-for-javascript-professionals/) allows-

- set the value of "this" to an specific object. This becomes very helpful as sometimes [this](http://javascriptissexy.com/understand-javascripts-this-with-clarity-and-master-it/) is not what is intended.
- reuse methods
- curry a function

For example, you have a function to deduct monthly club fees

```
function getMonthlyFee(fee){
  var remaining = this.total - fee;
  this.total = remaining;
  return this.name +' remaining balance:'+remaining;
}
```

Now you want to reuse this function for a different club member. Note that the monthly fee will vary from member to member.

Let's imagine Rachel has a balance of 500, and a monthly membership fee of 90.

```
var rachel = {name:'Rachel Green', total:500};
```

Now, create a function that can be used again and again to deduct the fee from her account every month

```
//bind
var getRachelFee = getMonthlyFee.bind(rachel, 90);
//deduct
getRachelFee();//Rachel Green remaining balance:410
getRachelFee();//Rachel Green remaining balance:320
```

Now, the same getMonthlyFee function could be used for another member with a different membership fee. For Example, Ross Geller has a 250 balance and a monthly fee of 25

```
var ross = {name:'Ross Geller', total:250};
//bind
var getRossFee = getMonthlyFee.bind(ross, 25);
//deduct
getRossFee(); //Ross Geller remaining balance:225
getRossFee(); //Ross Geller remaining balance:200
```

Comment: In your example I think I would be inclined to setup a member object instantiated with the new keyword where each member had their own properties/methods.  Then it's simply a matter of ross.getMonthlyFee(25).  Was this example just to just demonstrate the use of bind(), or is there some advantage to your approach?

Comment: love the curry a function one!

Comment: i dont know,  but i would do var getRachelFee = getMonthlyFee(rachel, 90);
And function would be function getMonthlyFee(member,fee){} something along the lines.

Comment: @KhanSharp Your answer is correct, but it is your references to TV-series Friends makes me comment and upvote. Thank you for you answer .

Answer (score 97):

From [**the MDN docs**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) on `Function.prototype.bind()` :

> The **bind()** method creates a new function that, when called, has its
>   this keyword set to the provided value, with a given sequence of
>   arguments preceding any provided when the new function is called.

So, what does that mean?!

Well, let's take a function that looks like this :

```
var logProp = function(prop) {
    console.log(this[prop]);
};
```

Now, let's take an object that looks like this :

```
var Obj = {
    x : 5,
    y : 10
};
```

We can bind our function to our object like this :

```
Obj.log = logProp.bind(Obj);
```

Now, we can run `Obj.log` anywhere in our code :

```
Obj.log('x'); // Output : 5
Obj.log('y'); // Output : 10
```

This works, because we bound the value of `this` to our object `Obj`.

---

Where it really gets interesting, is when you not only bind a value for `this`, but also for its argument `prop` :

```
Obj.logX = logProp.bind(Obj, 'x');
Obj.logY = logProp.bind(Obj, 'y');
```

We can now do this :

```
Obj.logX(); // Output : 5
Obj.logY(); // Output : 10
```

Unlike with `Obj.log`, we do not have to pass `x` or `y`, because we passed those values when we did our binding.

Comment: This answer should get more love. Well explained.

Comment: Very good combination of general overview and specific example.

Comment: Where's the button which shoots up straight 100 ups ?

Comment: With this I would also recommend reading MDN docs section of **Partially applied functions** to understand the use of bind "null". It should close off gates for most of the bind usage.


https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind

Comment: Thanks for this! A lot of people just link the documentation (or snarkily leave a LMGTFY link), but for beginners even the documentation can be hard to understand.

Answer (score 25):

Variables has local and global scopes. Let's suppose that we have two variables with the same name. One is globally defined and the other is defined inside a function closure and we want to get the variable value which is inside the function closure. In that case we use this bind() method. Please see the simple example below:

```js
var x = 9; // this refers to global "window" object here in the browser
var person = {
  x: 81,
  getX: function() {
    return this.x;
  }
};

var y = person.getX; // It will return 9, because it will call global value of x(var x=9).

var x2 = y.bind(person); // It will return 81, because it will call local value of x, which is defined in the object called person(x=81).

document.getElementById("demo1").innerHTML = y();
document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = x2();
```

```html
<p id="demo1">0</p>
<p id="demo2">0</p>
```

Answer (score 24):

### Summary:

The `bind()` method takes an object as an first argument and creates a new function. When  the function is invoked the value of `this` in the function body will be the object which was passed in as an argument in the `bind()` function.

### How does `this` work in JS anyway

The value of `this` in javascript is dependent always depends on what Object the function is called. **The value of `this` always refers to the object left of the dot from where the function is called**. In case of the global scope this is `window` (or `global` in `nodeJS`). Only `call`, `apply` and `bind` can alter the this binding differently. Here is an example to show how the this keyword works:

```js
let obj = {
  prop1: 1,
  func: function () { console.log(this); } 
}

obj.func();   // `obj` is left of the dot so `this` refers to `obj`

const customFunc = obj.func;  // we store the function in the customFunc obj

customFunc();  // now the object left of the dot is `window`, 
               // customFunc() is shorthand for window.customFunc()
               // Therefore window will be logged
```

### How is bind used?

Bind can help in overcoming difficulties with the `this` keyword by having a fixed object where `this` will refer to. For example:

```js
var name = 'globalName';

const obj = {
  name: 'myName',
  sayName: function () { console.log(this.name);}
}

const say = obj.sayName; // we are merely storing the function; the value of `this` isn't magically transferred

say(); // now because this function is executed in global scope, `this` will refer to the global var

const boundSay = obj.sayName.bind(obj); // now the value of `this` is bound to the `obj` object

boundSay();  // Now this will print the `name` in the `obj` object: 'myName'
```

Once the function is bound to a particular `this` value we can pass it around and even put it on properties on other objects. The value of `this` will remain the same.

Comment: Your comments in your code about the `obj` is the object because it is left of the dot and `window` is the the object because it is shorthand for `window.custFunc()` and `window` is left of the dot was very insightful for me.

Answer (score 14):

The bind() method creates a new function instance whose this value is bound to the value that was passed into bind(). 
For example:

```
   window.color = "red"; 
   var o = { color: "blue" }; 
   function sayColor(){ 
       alert(this.color); 
   } 
   var objectSayColor = sayColor.bind(o); 
   objectSayColor(); //blue
```

Here, a new function called objectSayColor() is created from sayColor() by calling bind() and passing in the object o. The objectSayColor() function has a this value equivalent to o, so calling the function, even as a global call, results in the string “blue” being displayed.

Reference : Nicholas C. Zakas - PROFESSIONAL JAVASCRIPT® FOR WEB DEVELOPERS

Comment: concise and laconic example

Answer (score 13):

## Creating a new Function by Binding Arguments to Values

The `bind` method creates a new function from another function with one or more arguments bound to specific values, including the implicit `this` argument.

#### Partial Application

This is an example of [partial application](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_application). Normally we supply a function with all of its arguments which yields a value. This is known as function application. We are applying the function to its arguments.

#### A Higher Order Function (HOF)

Partial application is an example of a [higher order function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higher-order_function) (HOF) because it yields a new function with a fewer number of argument.

#### Binding Multiple Arguments

You can use `bind` to transform functions with multiple arguments into new functions.

```js
function multiply(x, y) { 
    return x * y; 
}

let multiplyBy10 = multiply.bind(null, 10);
console.log(multiplyBy10(5));
```

#### Converting from Instance Method to Static Function

In the most common use case, when called with one argument the `bind` method will create a new function that has the `this` value bound to a specific value. In effect this transforms an instance method to a static method.

```js
function Multiplier(factor) { 
    this.factor = factor;
}

Multiplier.prototype.multiply = function(x) { 
    return this.factor * x; 
}

function ApplyFunction(func, value) {
    return func(value);
}

var mul = new Multiplier(5);

// Produces garbage (NaN) because multiplying "undefined" by 10
console.log(ApplyFunction(mul.multiply, 10));

// Produces expected result: 50
console.log(ApplyFunction(mul.multiply.bind(mul), 10));
```

#### Implementing a Stateful CallBack

The following example shows how using binding of `this` can enable an object method to act as a callback that can easily update the state of an object.

```js
function ButtonPressedLogger()
{
   this.count = 0;
   this.onPressed = function() {
      this.count++;
      console.log("pressed a button " + this.count + " times");
   }
   for (let d of document.getElementsByTagName("button"))
      d.onclick = this.onPressed.bind(this);
}

new ButtonPressedLogger();
```

```html
<button>press me</button>
<button>no press me</button>
```

Answer (score 12):

I will explain bind theoretically as well as practically

bind in javascript is a method -- Function.prototype.bind . bind is a  method. It is called on function prototype. This method creates a function whose body is similar to the function on which it is called but the 'this' refers to the first parameter passed to the bind method. Its syntax is

```
     var bindedFunc = Func.bind(thisObj,optionsArg1,optionalArg2,optionalArg3,...);
```

Example:--

```
  var checkRange = function(value){
      if(typeof value !== "number"){
              return false;
      }
      else {
         return value >= this.minimum && value <= this.maximum;
      }
  }

  var range = {minimum:10,maximum:20};

  var boundedFunc = checkRange.bind(range); //bounded Function. this refers to range
  var result = boundedFunc(15); //passing value
  console.log(result) // will give true;
```

Comment: It basically makes whatever 'this' inside the function into whatever object you pass in, correct?

Answer (score 7):

As mentioned, `Function.bind()` lets you specify the context that the function will execute in (that is, it lets you pass in what object the `this` keyword will resolve to in the body of the function.

A couple of analogous toolkit API methods that perform a similar service:

[jQuery.proxy()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.proxy/)

[Dojo.hitch()](https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojo/_base/lang.html#dojo-base-lang-hitch)

Answer (score 4):

## [Bind Method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind)

A bind implementation might look something like so:

```
Function.prototype.bind = function () {
  const self = this;
  const args = [...arguments];
  const context = args.shift();

  return function () {
    return self.apply(context, args.concat([...arguments]));
  };
};
```

The bind function can take any number of arguments and **return a new function**.

**The new function** will call the original function using the JS `Function.prototype.apply` method.

The `apply` method will use the first argument passed to the target function as its context (`this`), and the second array argument of the `apply` method will be a combination of the rest of the arguments from the target function, concat with the arguments used to call the return function (in that order).

An example can look something like so:

```js
function Fruit(emoji) {
  this.emoji = emoji;
}

Fruit.prototype.show = function () {
  console.log(this.emoji);
};

const apple = new Fruit('');
const orange = new Fruit('');

apple.show();  // 
orange.show(); // 

const fruit1 = apple.show;
const fruit2 = apple.show.bind();
const fruit3 = apple.show.bind(apple);
const fruit4 = apple.show.bind(orange);

fruit1(); // undefined
fruit2(); // undefined
fruit3(); // 
fruit4(); //
```

Answer (score 3):

```
/**
 * Bind is a method inherited from Function.prototype same like call and apply
 * It basically helps to bind a function to an object's context during initialisation 
 * 
 * */

window.myname = "Jineesh";  
var foo = function(){ 
  return this.myname;
};

//IE < 8 has issues with this, supported in ecmascript 5
var obj = { 
    myname : "John", 
    fn:foo.bind(window)// binds to window object
}; 
console.log( obj.fn() ); // Returns Jineesh
```

Answer (score 3):

Consider the Simple Program listed below,

```
//we create object user
let User = { name: 'Justin' };

//a Hello Function is created to Alert the object User 
function Hello() {
  alert(this.name);
}

//since there the value of this is lost we need to bind user to use this keyword
let user = Hello.bind(User);
user();

//we create an instance to refer the this keyword (this.name);
```

Answer (score 3):

**Simple Explanation:**

**bind()** create a new function, a new reference at a function it returns to you.

In parameter after this keyword, you pass in the parameter you want to preconfigure. Actually it does not execute immediately, just prepares for execution.

You can preconfigure as many parameters as you want.

**Simple Example to understand bind:**

```js
function calculate(operation) {
  if (operation === 'ADD') {
   alert('The Operation is Addition');
  } else if (operation === 'SUBTRACT') {
   alert('The Operation is Subtraction');
  }
}

addBtn.addEventListener('click', calculate.bind(this, 'ADD'));
subtractBtn.addEventListener('click', calculate.bind(this, 'SUBTRACT'));
```

Answer (score 3):

## Here's the simplest possible explanation:

Say you have a function

```
function _loop(n) { console.log("so: " + n) }
```

obviously you can call it like `_loop(69)` as usual.

## Rewrite like this:

```
var _loop = function() { console.log("so: " + this.n) }
```

Notice there are now

- no arguments as such
- you use "this. " to get to the named arguments

You can now call the function like this:

```
 _loop.bind( {"n": 420} )
```

That's it.

## Most typical use case:

A really typical use is when you need to **add an argument to a callback**.

Callbacks can't have arguments.

So just "rewrite" the callback as above.

Answer (score 2):

The bind function creates a new function with the same function body as the function it is calling .It is called with the this argument .why we use bind fun. : when every time  a new instance is created and we have to use first initial instance then we use bind fun.We can't override the bind fun.simply it stores the initial object of the class.

```
setInterval(this.animate_to.bind(this), 1000/this.difference);
```

Answer (score 2):

- function.prototype.bind() accepts an Object.
- It binds the calling function to the passed Object and the returns
  the same.
- When an object is bound to a function, it means you will be able to
  access the values of that object from within the function using
  'this' keyword.

It can also be said as,

> function.prototype.bind() is used to provide/change the context of a
> function.

```js
let powerOfNumber = function(number) {
  let product = 1;
    for(let i=1; i<= this.power; i++) {
      product*=number;
  }
  return product;
}


let powerOfTwo = powerOfNumber.bind({power:2});
alert(powerOfTwo(2));

let powerOfThree = powerOfNumber.bind({power:3});
alert(powerOfThree(2));

let powerOfFour = powerOfNumber.bind({power:4});
alert(powerOfFour(2));
```

Let us try to understand this.

```
    let powerOfNumber = function(number) {
      let product = 1;
      for (let i = 1; i <= this.power; i++) {
        product *= number;
      }
      return product;
    }
```

Here, in this function, this corresponds to the object bound to the function powerOfNumber. Currently we don't have any function that is bound to this function.

Let us create a function powerOfTwo which will find the second power of a number using the above function.

```
  let powerOfTwo = powerOfNumber.bind({power:2});
  alert(powerOfTwo(2));
```

Here the object {power : 2} is passed to powerOfNumber function using bind.

The bind function binds this object to the powerOfNumber() and returns the below function to powerOfTwo. Now, powerOfTwo looks like,

```
    let powerOfNumber = function(number) {
      let product = 1;
        for(let i=1; i<=2; i++) {
          product*=number;
      }
      return product;
    }
```

Hence, powerOfTwo will find the second power.

Feel free to check this out.

[bind() function in Javascript](https://vanmeeganathan.hashnode.dev/bind-function-in-javascript)

Answer (score 2):

The bind() method creates a new function that, when called, has its `this` keyword set to the provided value, with a given sequence of arguments preceding any provided when the new function is called.

**An example for the first part**

> grabbed from react package [useSt8](https://github.com/mweststrate/use-st8)

```
import { useState } from "react"

function st8() {
    switch(arguments.length) {
        case 0: return this[0]
        case 1: return void this[1](arguments[0])
        default: throw new Error("Expected 0 or 1 arguments")
    }
}


function useSt8(initial) {
    // this in st8 will be something like [state, setSatate]
    return st8.bind(useState(initial))
}

// usage
function Counter() {
  const count = useSt8(0);
  return (
    <>
      Count: {count()}
      <button onClick={() => count(0)}>Reset</button>
      <button onClick={() => count(prevCount => prevCount + 1)}>inc</button>
    </>
  );
}
```

**An example for the second part**

```js
const add = (a, b) => a+b

someThis = this
// new function with this value equal to someThis
add5 = add.bind(someThis, 5) 
add5(10) // 15

// we don't use this in add decelartion so this will work too.
add10 = add.bind(null, 10) 
add10(5) // 15
```

Answer (score 1):

### Simple example

```
function lol(second, third) {
    console.log(this.first, second, third);
}

lol(); // undefined, undefined, undefined
lol('1'); // undefined, "1", undefined
lol('1', '2'); // undefined, "1", "2"

lol.call({first: '1'}); // "1", undefined, undefined
lol.call({first: '1'}, '2'); // "1", "2", undefined
lol.call({first: '1'}, '2', '3'); // "1", "2", "3"

lol.apply({first: '1'}); // "1", undefined, undefined
lol.apply({first: '1'}, ['2', '3']); // "1", "2", "3"

const newLol = lol.bind({first: '1'}); 
newLol(); // "1", undefined, undefined
newLol('2'); // "1", "2", undefined
newLol('2', '3'); // "1", "2", "3"

const newOmg = lol.bind({first: '1'}, '2');
newOmg(); // "1", "2", undefined
newOmg('3'); // "1", "2", "3"

const newWtf = lol.bind({first: '1'}, '2', '3');
newWtf(); // "1", "2", "3"
```

Answer (score 0):

Another usage is that you can pass binded function as an argument to another function which is operating under another execution context.

```
var name = "sample";
function sample(){
  console.log(this.name);
}
var cb = sample.bind(this);

function somefunction(cb){
  //other code
  cb();
}
somefunction.call({}, cb);
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what have been said, the `bind()` method allows an object to borrow a method from another object without making a copy of that method. This is known as **function borrowing** in JavaScript.

Comment: What do you mean by "without making a copy"?

Comment: It means that u don't need to copy the function code and paste it in any other object that needs this functionality; It's a great way to extend the functionality. @Bergi

Comment: You never need to copy source code. You can just assign the existing function onto your other object, you don't need to use `bind` for that.

Answer (score 0):

i did not read above code but i learn something in simple so want to share here about bind method after bind method we can use it as any normal method.

```
<pre> note: do not use arrow function it will show error undefined  </pre>
```

```js
let solarSystem = {
    sun: 'red',
    moon : 'white',
    sunmoon : function(){
       let dayNight = this.sun + ' is the sun color and present in day and '+this.moon + ' is the moon color and prenet in night';
        return dayNight;
    }
}

let work = function(work,sleep){
    console.log(this.sunmoon()); // accessing the solatSystem it show error undefine sunmmon untill now because we can't access directly for that we use .bind()
    console.log('i work in '+ work +' and sleep in '+sleep);
}

let outPut = work.bind(solarSystem);
outPut('day','night')
```

Answer (score -1):

bind is a function which is available in java script prototype, as the name suggest bind is used to bind your function call to the  context whichever you are dealing with for eg:

```js
    var rateOfInterest='4%';
    var axisBank=
    {
    rateOfInterest:'10%',
    getRateOfInterest:function()
    {
    return this.rateOfInterest;
    }
    }
    axisBank.getRateOfInterest() //'10%' 


    let knowAxisBankInterest=axisBank.getRateOfInterest // when you want to assign the function call to a varaible we use this syntax
    knowAxisBankInterest(); // you will get output as '4%' here by default the function is called wrt global context

let knowExactAxisBankInterest=knowAxisBankInterest.bind(axisBank);     //so here we need bind function call  to its local context


    knowExactAxisBankInterest() // '10%'
```