# Using "Object.create" instead of "new"

Tags: javascript, constructor, new-operator, object-create

Javascript 1.9.3 / ECMAScript 5 introduces `Object.create`, which Douglas Crockford amongst others has been [advocating](http://javascript.crockford.com/prototypal.html) for a long time. How do I replace `new` in the code below with `Object.create`?

```
var UserA = function(nameParam) {
    this.id = MY_GLOBAL.nextId();
    this.name = nameParam;
}
UserA.prototype.sayHello = function() {
    console.log('Hello '+ this.name);
}
var bob = new UserA('bob');
bob.sayHello();
```

(Assume `MY_GLOBAL.nextId` exists).

The best I can come up with is:

```
var userB = {
    init: function(nameParam) {
        this.id = MY_GLOBAL.nextId();
        this.name = nameParam;
    },
    sayHello: function() {
        console.log('Hello '+ this.name);
    }
};
var bob = Object.create(userB);
bob.init('Bob');
bob.sayHello();
```

There doesn't seem to be any advantage, so I think I'm not getting it. I'm probably being too neo-classical. How should I use `Object.create` to create user 'bob'?

Comment: When the accepted answer has less votes than the question, maybe the accepted answer isn't acceptable? @CMS would have you write a factory function that uses `Object.create` internally to get the same single-step functionality as `new UserA('bob');`.

Comment: Perhaps its the *most* acceptable answer, considering it has the most votes of all 6 answers.

Comment: See also [Understanding the difference between Object.create() and new SomeFunction()](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4166616/1048572)

Comment: Crockford was an early guiding sage in the JS world, but his heyday is past.  His suggestion to stop using `new` altogether never caught on, even though `Object.create` is useful in other ways.

Comment: @Andy the reason for this relies on the paradigm you use. If you use functional programming in JS you prefer Object.create rather than new keyword.

Answer (score 267, accepted):

With only one level of inheritance, your example may not let you see the real benefits of [`Object.create`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create).

This methods allows you to easily implement *differential inheritance*, where objects can directly inherit from other objects.

On your `userB` example, I don't think that your `init` method should be public or even exist, if you call again this method on an existing object instance, the `id` and `name` properties will change.

`Object.create` lets you initialize object properties using its second argument, e.g.:

```
var userB = {
  sayHello: function() {
    console.log('Hello '+ this.name);
  }
};

var bob = Object.create(userB, {
  'id' : {
    value: MY_GLOBAL.nextId(),
    enumerable:true // writable:false, configurable(deletable):false by default
  },
  'name': {
    value: 'Bob',
    enumerable: true
  }
});
```

As you can see, the properties can be initialized on the second argument of `Object.create`, with an object literal using a syntax similar to the used by the `Object.defineProperties` and `Object.defineProperty` methods.

It lets you set the property attributes (`enumerable`, `writable`, or `configurable`), which can be really useful.

Comment: 1. Thanks for the pointer to differential inheritance.
2. Does this mean no more constructors? I need to remember to set 'id' to MY_GLOBAL.nextId() every time I create a user?

Comment: You're welcome @Graham, you're right, no more constructors needed with this method, although the  currently available implementations on Firefox 3.7apre5, the latest WebKit Nightly builds and Chrome 5 Beta, are [not so fast](http://webreflection.blogspot.com/2010/03/new-constructor-vs-objectcreate.html) compared with plain old constructors, hopefully this will change in the near future. For the object creation, you could create a *factory* function(i.e. `function createUser(name) { ... }`, with all the needed logic to create your user objects within with `Object.create`.

Comment: Re: no more constructors: Normally you'd write an ordinary function to be the "factory" for objects. Internally it would use `Object.create` to make a blank object, and then modify it as necessary before returning it. The caller of that factory doesn't have to remember the prefix `new`.

Comment: @CMS When would or wouldn't you want to set enumerable to true?

Comment: @GrahamKing You could use a closure to init your objects: http://jsfiddle.net/Prqdt/

Comment: @CMS What is *differential inheritance*?Why is it called so?

Comment: @CMS ", if you call again this method on an existing object instance, the id and name properties will change.". Wait, how? `this` is referring to the new object with its own name and id properties. Why would calling `init` on an different object with the same prototype change those properties?

Comment: Passing in the 2nd param a properties object does not initialize the new object to have those properties. I have to set them directly, line by line. var model = Object.create(parent); model.someFunction = someFunction; function someFunction(){...}

Comment: it is not inheritance, it is object composition

Comment: @ryanve when the object has some private property that you don't want to be enumerated (e.g. in a `for in` where you don't want to list object metadata but just actual data properties). See [MDN Enumerability](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Enumerability_and_ownership_of_properties)

Comment: @Geek see [Differential Inheritance on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_inheritance)

Comment: @linstantnoodles he didn't write "different object" but "existing"; I think the emphasis is on "again", since the *public* `init` method replaces the (kind of private) `constructor`, but might be called multiple times and cause undesired results; initialisation should happen just once.

Answer (score 56):

There is really no advantage in using `Object.create(...)` over `new object`.

Those advocating this method generally state rather ambiguous advantages: ["scalability"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7505546), or "[more natural to JavaScript](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/html5/articles/javascript-object-creation.html)" etc.

However, I have yet to see a concrete example that shows that `Object.create` has *any* advantages over using `new`. On the contrary there are known problems with it. [Sam Elsamman describes what happens when there are nested objects and `Object.create(...)` is used](http://elsamman.com/?p=32):

```
var Animal = {
    traits: {},
}
var lion = Object.create(Animal);
lion.traits.legs = 4;
var bird = Object.create(Animal);
bird.traits.legs = 2;
alert(lion.traits.legs) // shows 2!!!
```

This occurs because `Object.create(...)` advocates a practice where *data* is used to create new objects; here the `Animal` datum becomes part of the prototype of `lion` and `bird`, and causes problems as it is shared. When using new the prototypal inheritance is explicit:

```
function Animal() {
    this.traits = {};
}

function Lion() { }
Lion.prototype = new Animal();
function Bird() { }
Bird.prototype = new Animal();

var lion = new Lion();
lion.traits.legs = 4;
var bird = new Bird();
bird.traits.legs = 2;
alert(lion.traits.legs) // now shows 4
```

Regarding, the optional property attributes that are passed into `Object.create(...)`, these can be added using [`Object.defineProperties(...)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperties).

Comment: I disagree. `Object.create` neither enforces nor encourages the practice of using prototypes as any kind of "storage for default data values" as the linked article seems to suggest. Proper data initialization is the responsibility of whoever creates a particular object (like a factory or builder in the OO design). *(Inheriting data rather than behaviour is feasible in JS, but not a common scenario.)*

Comment: As long as you understand that the argument to Object.create is supposed to be the prototype, this problem shouldn't come up. Obviously you can get the same bad behavior when using **new** if you say Animal.prototype.traits = {};  The only reason it's clear you shouldn't do that is that you understand how javascript prototypes work.

Comment: God god! So many downvotes for providing the right answer :-) The point is Object.create does not permit a mechanism for constructor arguments so one is forced to extend "data". Now this data may contain nested objects, which leads to the problem above. With prototypal inheritance on the other hand we only run into this problem if we were to _explicitly_ write out `Animal.prototype.traits = {};`. One method is implicit the other explicit. Don't chose the one that leads to problems.

Comment: In the second example, the two objects don't share the common prototype (although they do share the next one in the chain). If you want both animals to have their own traits property, you could apply the Animal function to both bird and lion, and they will each get a traits property directly (no prototype, and not shared). There may times when you want things to be shared (like you don't want to recreate all the functions each time a new object is created), and I think that is when you make use of the prototype.

Comment: Problem with using `new` with a subtype this way is that you never want to specify arguments for the supertype ctor, since you don't have the data at this point. Suddenly you need to insert a conditional in your supertype ctor to check if the arguments are provided or not; but what if you don't want a default ctor? There is no way that I know of to determine whether the call was done to setup the prototype of a subtype or to setup the data of the supertype in the subtype ctor.

Comment: [Please see this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3191103/javascript-object-create-inheriting-nested-properties) for a simple solution to the 2 legged lion. [Here's some working code to illustrate it](http://jsfiddle.net/d131/a6xhu/)

Comment: I would suggest reading this article by Kyle Simpson.  All three parts are interesting, but part 3 is key.  If after reading those you still think "new" is better than Object.create(), then there is no hope for you! :) http://davidwalsh.name/javascript-objects-deconstruction

Comment: To be fair, the second example should be completed so: `var clarence = new Lion(); clarence.traits.legs = 3; console.log(lion.traits.legs) // 3, shit!`

Comment: If you were using Object.create with the proper conceptual understanding of prototypes, you would say "Of course it doesn't work that way! The shared prototype is a feature, not a bug!"

Comment: To clarify, we can share multiple methods from multiple prototype objects with the help of Object.Create.  This sharing flexibility is clearly an "advantage" over new, and part of the beauty of JavaScript.

Comment: What javascript proves is that if you build the foundations out of crap, all subsequent layers of the house will also be crap.

Answer (score 42):

Object.create is not yet standard on several browsers, for example IE8, Opera v11.5, Konq 4.3 do not have it. You can use Douglas Crockford's version of Object.create for those browsers but this doesn't include the second 'initialisation object' parameter used in CMS's answer.

For cross browser code one way to get object initialisation in the meantime is to customise Crockford's Object.create. Here is one method:-

```
Object.build = function(o) {
   var initArgs = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments,1)
   function F() {
      if((typeof o.init === 'function') && initArgs.length) {
         o.init.apply(this,initArgs)
      }
   }
   F.prototype = o
   return new F()
}
```

This maintains Crockford prototypal inheritance, and also checks for any init method in the object, then runs it with your parameter(s), like say new man('John','Smith'). Your code then becomes:-

```
MY_GLOBAL = {i: 1, nextId: function(){return this.i++}}  // For example

var userB = {
    init: function(nameParam) {
        this.id = MY_GLOBAL.nextId();
        this.name = nameParam;
    },
    sayHello: function() {
        console.log('Hello '+ this.name);
    }
};
var bob = Object.build(userB, 'Bob');  // Different from your code
bob.sayHello();
```

So bob inherits the sayHello method and now has own properties id=1 and name='Bob'. These properties are both writable and enumerable of course. This is also a much simpler way to initialise than for ECMA Object.create especially if you aren't concerned about the writable, enumerable and configurable attributes.

For initialisation without an init method the following Crockford mod could be used:-

```
Object.gen = function(o) {
   var makeArgs = arguments 
   function F() {
      var prop, i=1, arg, val
      for(prop in o) {
         if(!o.hasOwnProperty(prop)) continue
         val = o[prop]
         arg = makeArgs[i++]
         if(typeof arg === 'undefined') break
         this[prop] = arg
      }
   }
   F.prototype = o
   return new F()
}
```

This fills the userB own properties, in the order they are defined, using the Object.gen parameters from left to right after the userB parameter. It uses the for(prop in o) loop so, by ECMA standards, the order of property enumeration cannot be guaranteed the same as the order of property definition. However, several code examples tested on (4) major browsers show they are the same, provided the hasOwnProperty filter is used, and sometimes even if not.

```
MY_GLOBAL = {i: 1, nextId: function(){return this.i++}};  // For example

var userB = {
   name: null,
   id: null,
   sayHello: function() {
      console.log('Hello '+ this.name);
   }
}

var bob = Object.gen(userB, 'Bob', MY_GLOBAL.nextId());
```

Somewhat simpler I would say than Object.build since userB does not need an init method. Also userB is not specifically a constructor but looks like a normal singleton object. So with this method you can construct and initialise from normal plain objects.

Comment: There is a polyfill for `Object.create` in the ES5 Shim https://github.com/kriskowal/es5-shim

Comment: Great article! I've added a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AV7sV/), so you have a working example for both Object.build and Object.gen in one file. Also, I've added some semicolons which were missing (available in JSFiddle only).

Answer (score 28):

TL;DR:

`new Computer()` will invoke the constructor function `Computer(){}` for one time, while `Object.create(Computer.prototype)` won't.

All the advantages are based on this point.

Sidenote about performance: Constructor invoking like `new Computer()` is heavily optimized by the engine, so it may be even faster than `Object.create`.

Answer (score 14):

You could make the `init` method return `this`, and then chain the calls together, like this:

```
var userB = {
    init: function(nameParam) {
        this.id = MY_GLOBAL.nextId();
        this.name = nameParam;
        return this;
    },
    sayHello: function() {
        console.log('Hello '+ this.name);
    }
};

var bob = Object.create(userB).init('Bob');
```

Comment: One can further do `create = Object.create.bind(Object); log = console.log.bind(console)` and then one can just write `create(...)` and `log(...)`. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10115970/1658543) for what `.bind(...)` does.

Answer (score 10):

Another possible usage of Object.create is to clone immutable objects in a [cheap and effective way](http://jsperf.com/object-clone).

```
var anObj = {
    a: "test",
    b: "jest"
};

var bObj = Object.create(anObj);

bObj.b = "gone"; // replace an existing (by masking prototype)
bObj.c = "brand"; // add a new to demonstrate it is actually a new obj

// now bObj is {a: test, b: gone, c: brand}
```

**Notes**: The above snippet creates a clone of an source object (aka not a reference, as in cObj = aObj). It benefits over the copy-properties method (see [1](http://jsperf.com/object-clone)), in that it does not copy object member properties. Rather it creates another -destination- object with it's prototype set on the source object. Moreover when properties are modified on the dest object, they are created "on the fly", masking the prototype's (src's) properties.This constitutes a fast an effective way of cloning immutable objects.

The caveat here is that this applies to source objects that should not be modified after creation (immutable). If the source object is modified after creation, all the clone's unmasked properties will be modified, too.

Fiddle here(http://jsfiddle.net/y5b5q/1/) (needs Object.create capable browser).

Comment: Calling this clone is confusing to me (and probably many others).  To most people a `clone` method implies that changes to the original would not affect the clone.

Comment: Understood, I amended the answer to account only for source objects considered immutable.

Comment: Cloning objects repeatedly this way will quickly get you into trouble, as you'll have an object with a really long prototype chain that keeps all those old objects in memory.  I'll sometimes use `Object.create` in testing to make mocks that override some properties of an *instance* of a class while keeping others the same.  But I rarely use it.

Comment: I checked the above code and may be `Object.create` has evolved but for now `Object.create` is not cloning anything and the result of the code `var bObj = Object.create(anObj); console.log(bObj);` is `{}` means no properties are copied.

Answer (score 7):

I think the main point in question - is to understand difference between `new` and `Object.create` approaches. Accordingly to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3658673/3612353) and to [this video](https://app.pluralsight.com/player?course=advanced-javascript&author=kyle-simpson&name=advanced-javascript-m2&clip=19&mode=live) `new` keyword does next things:

1. Creates new object.
2. Links new object to constructor function (`prototype`).
3. Makes `this` variable point to the new object.
4. Executes constructor function using the new object and implicit perform `return this`;
5. Assigns constructor function name to new object's property `constructor`.

`Object.create` performs only `1st` and `2nd` steps!!!

In code example provided in question it isn't big deal, but in next example it is:

```
var onlineUsers = [];
function SiteMember(name) {
    this.name = name;
    onlineUsers.push(name);
}
SiteMember.prototype.getName = function() {
    return this.name;
}
function Guest(name) {
    SiteMember.call(this, name);
}
Guest.prototype = new SiteMember();

var g = new Guest('James');
console.log(onlineUsers);
```

As side effect result will be:

```
[ undefined, 'James' ]
```

because of `Guest.prototype = new SiteMember();`

But we don't need to execute parent constructor method, we need only make method `getName` to be available in Guest.
Hence we have to use `Object.create`.

If replace `Guest.prototype = new SiteMember();`

to `Guest.prototype = Object.create(SiteMember.prototype);` result be:

```
[ 'James' ]
```

Comment: This is bad example of using Object,create to solve combination inheritance (constructor stealing + prototype chaining) major failing which is that parent constructor is called twice. Object.create creates new object using existing object as prototype which means one more prototype in the chain. The mentioned failing is solved using  parasitic combination inheritance (constructor stealing + hybrid prototype chaining). We only need to copy parent prototype and it can be done like this:  var prototype = new Object(SiteMember.prototype); prototype.constructor = Guest; Guest.prototype = prototype;

Answer (score 6):

Sometimes you cannot create an object with NEW but are still able to invoke the CREATE method.

For example: if you want to define a Custom Element it must derive from HTMLElement.

```
proto = new HTMLElement  //fail :(
proto = Object.create( HTMLElement.prototype )  //OK :)
document.registerElement( "custom-element", { prototype: proto } )
```

Answer (score 4):

The advantage is that `Object.create` is typically slower than `new` on most browsers

[In this jsperf example](http://jsperf.com/object-create-vs-constructor-vs-object-literal/49), in a Chromium, browser `new` is **30 times as fast** as `Object.create(obj)` although both are pretty fast. This is all pretty strange because new does more things (like invoking a constructor) where Object.create should be just creating a new Object with the passed in object as a prototype (secret link in Crockford-speak)

Perhaps the browsers have not caught up in making `Object.create` more efficient (perhaps they are basing it on `new` under the covers ... even in native code)

Comment: That jsperf appears to be gone.

Answer (score 4):

### Summary:

- `Object.create()` is a Javascript function which takes 2 arguments and returns a new object.
- The first argument is an object which will be the prototype of the newly created object
- The second argument is an object which will be the properties of the newly created object

### Example:

```js
const proto = {
  talk : () => console.log('hi')
}

const props = {
  age: {
    writable: true,
    configurable: true,
    value: 26
  }
}


let Person = Object.create(proto, props)

console.log(Person.age);
Person.talk();
```

### Practical applications:

1. The main advantage of creating an object in this manner is that **the prototype can be explicitly defined**. When using an object literal, or the `new` keyword you have no control over this (however, you can overwrite them of course).
2. If we want to have a prototype The `new` keyword invokes a constructor function. With `Object.create()` there is **no need for invoking or even declaring a constructor function**.
3. It can Basically be a helpful tool when you want create objects in a very dynamic manner. We can make an object factory function which creates objects with different prototypes depending on the arguments received.

Answer (score 3):

You have to make a custom `Object.create()` function. One that addresses Crockfords concerns and also calls your init function.

This will work:

```
var userBPrototype = {
    init: function(nameParam) {
        this.name = nameParam;
    },
    sayHello: function() {
        console.log('Hello '+ this.name);
    }
};


function UserB(name) {
    function F() {};
    F.prototype = userBPrototype;
    var f = new F;
    f.init(name);
    return f;
}

var bob = UserB('bob');
bob.sayHello();
```

Here UserB is like Object.create, but adjusted for our needs.

If you want, you can also call:

```
var bob = new UserB('bob');
```

Comment: Why not just have `UserB` say `var f = Object.create(userPrototype); f.init(name); return f;` ?

Comment: init might be called several times. nothing preventing that.

Answer (score 3):

While Douglas Crockford used to be a zealous advocate of Object.create() and he is basically the reason why this construct actually is in javascript, he no longer has this opinion.

He stopped using Object.create, because he stopped using *this* keyword altogether as it causes too much trouble. For example, if you are not careful it can easily point to the global object, which can have really bad consequences. And he claims that without using *this* Object.create does not make sense anymore.

You can check this video from 2014 where he talks at Nordic.js:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PSGEjv3Tqo0

[image]

Answer (score 3):

`new` and `Object.create` serve different purposes. `new` is intended to create a new instance of an object type. `Object.create` is intended to simply create a new object and set its prototype. Why is this useful? To implement inheritance without accessing the `__proto__` property.  An object instance's prototype referred to as `[[Prototype]]` is an internal property of the virtual machine and is not intended to be directly accessed. The only reason it is actually possible to directly access `[[Prototype]]` as the `__proto__` property is because it has always been a de-facto standard of every major virtual machine's implementation of ECMAScript, and at this point removing it would break a lot of existing code.

In response to the answer above by 7ochem, objects should absolutely never have their prototype set to the result of a `new` statement, not only because there's no point calling the same prototype constructor multiple times but also because two instances of the same class can end up with different behavior if one's prototype is modified after being created. Both examples are simply bad code as a result of misunderstanding and breaking the intended behavior of the prototype inheritance chain.

Instead of accessing `__proto__`, an instance's prototype should be written to when an it is created with `Object.create` or afterward with `Object.setPrototypeOf`, and read with `Object.getPrototypeOf` or `Object.isPrototypeOf`.

Also, as the [Mozilla documentation of Object.setPrototypeOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/setPrototypeOf) points out, it is a bad idea to modify the prototype of an object after it is created for performance reasons, in addition to the fact that modifying an object's prototype after it is created can cause undefined behavior if a given piece of code that accesses it can be executed before OR after the prototype is modified, unless that code is very careful to check the current prototype or not access any property that differs between the two.

Given

`const X = function (v) { this.v = v };
X.prototype.whatAmI = 'X';
X.prototype.getWhatIAm = () => this.whatAmI;
X.prototype.getV = () => this.v;`

the following VM pseudo-code is equivalent to the statement `const x0 = new X(1);`:

`const x0 = {};
x0.[[Prototype]] = X.prototype;
X.prototype.constructor.call(x0, 1);`

Note although the constructor can return any value, the `new` statement always ignores its return value and returns a reference to the newly created object.

And the following pseudo-code is equivalent to the statement `const x1 = Object.create(X.prototype);`:

`const x0 = {};
x0.[[Prototype]] = X.prototype;`

As you can see, the only difference between the two is that `Object.create` does not execute the constructor, which can actually return any value but simply returns the new object reference `this` if not otherwise specified.

Now, if we wanted to create a subclass Y with the following definition:

`const Y = function(u) { this.u = u; }
Y.prototype.whatAmI = 'Y';
Y.prototype.getU = () => this.u;`

Then we can make it inherit from X like this by writing to `__proto__`:

`Y.prototype.__proto__ = X.prototype;`

While the same thing could be accomplished without ever writing to `__proto__` with:

`Y.prototype = Object.create(X.prototype);
Y.prototype.constructor = Y;`

In the latter case, it is necessary to set the constructor property of the prototype so that the correct constructor is called by the `new Y` statement, otherwise `new Y` will call the function `X`. If the programmer does want `new Y` to call `X`, it would be more properly done in Y's constructor with `X.call(this, u)`

Answer (score 3):

#### `new` Operator

- This is used to create object from a constructor function
- The `new` keywords also executes the constructor function

```
function Car() {
  console.log(this) // this points to myCar
  this.name = "Honda";
}

var myCar = new Car()
console.log(myCar) // Car {name: "Honda", constructor: Object}
console.log(myCar.name) // Honda
console.log(myCar instanceof Car) // true
console.log(myCar.constructor) // function Car() {}
console.log(myCar.constructor === Car) // true
console.log(typeof myCar) // object
```

#### Object.create

- You can also use `Object.create` to create a new object
- But, it does not execute the constructor function
- `Object.create` is used to create an object from another object

```
const Car = {
  name: "Honda"
}

var myCar = Object.create(Car)
console.log(myCar) // Object {}
console.log(myCar.name) // Honda
console.log(myCar instanceof Car) // ERROR
console.log(myCar.constructor) // Anonymous function object
console.log(myCar.constructor === Car) // false
console.log(typeof myCar) // object
```

Comment: Good catch - there was a typo. Fixed it now.

Answer (score 2):

I prefer a closure approach.

I still use `new`.
I don't use `Object.create`.
I don't use `this`.

I still use `new` as I like the declarative nature of it.

Consider this for simple inheritance.

```
window.Quad = (function() {

    function Quad() {

        const wheels = 4;
        const drivingWheels = 2;

        let motorSize = 0;

        function setMotorSize(_) {
            motorSize = _;
        }

        function getMotorSize() {
            return motorSize;
        }

        function getWheelCount() {
            return wheels;
        }

        function getDrivingWheelCount() {
            return drivingWheels;
        }
        return Object.freeze({
            getWheelCount,
            getDrivingWheelCount,
            getMotorSize,
            setMotorSize
        });
    }

    return Object.freeze(Quad);
})();

window.Car4wd = (function() {

    function Car4wd() {
        const quad = new Quad();

        const spareWheels = 1;
        const extraDrivingWheels = 2;

        function getSpareWheelCount() {
            return spareWheels;
        }

        function getDrivingWheelCount() {
            return quad.getDrivingWheelCount() + extraDrivingWheels;
        }

        return Object.freeze(Object.assign({}, quad, {
            getSpareWheelCount,
            getDrivingWheelCount
        }));
    }

    return Object.freeze(Car4wd);
})();

let myQuad = new Quad();
let myCar = new Car4wd();
console.log(myQuad.getWheelCount()); // 4
console.log(myQuad.getDrivingWheelCount()); // 2
console.log(myCar.getWheelCount()); // 4
console.log(myCar.getDrivingWheelCount()); // 4 - The overridden method is called
console.log(myCar.getSpareWheelCount()); // 1
```

Feedback encouraged.

Comment: This is intriguing.  Could you extend the example to show how you would implement setters?  Or would Object.freeze() prevent that?

Comment: The freeze is just stopping the runtime modification of the "class".  I've extended the example of the parent with a local variable in the closure and a getter and setter to show managing the "private" variable in the closure

Comment: Re Feedback, can you give code that creates an instance please?  I feel like this is 'server' code and that no 'client' code has been given.

Comment: The instance creation happens at the end of the example with the following lines

let myQuad = new Quad();

let myCar = new Car4wd();

this is client code, it uses the window object to store the types/classes