# Copy and modify similar object for instantiation javascript

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, object

I have an object that looks like

```
var customObject = function() {
    this.property = "value";
};

customObject.prototype = new otherObject();

customObject.prototype.property2 = function() {};
```

etc. - it's much bigger than this.

I can successfully instantiate the object by writing `new customObject()`.

Now I would like to create a rather similar object, although a little different. This involves modifying certain properties and perhaps even adding or removing some. As in the above example, I would like it to be invokable by writing `new customObject2()`.

I thought I could simply do:

```
var customObject2 = new customObject();
customObject2.prototype = customObject.prototype;
customObject2.property = "modified value";
```

etc.

However, when I try to instantiate it by doing `new customObject2()` I receive an error, stating that the customObject2 is not a function.

I hope I could illustrate well enough as to what pattern I desire to create. What approach should I take to create such a pattern?

Comment: Well looking at your code, you're doing `customObject2 = new customObject()`. That should explain why it's not a function

Comment: Is there some quick way to get what I need? Or am I supposed to manually create a `var customObject2 = function() {};` and loop over all the direct properties of the original `customObject` to assign them to the `this` of `customObject2`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `customObject` is not a host object (i.e. won't give you an illegal invocation error if you try to call it differently to expected) you can *apply* the constructor to a different `this` *Object*;

```
var customObject2 = function () {
    customObject.call(this); // construct as if `customObject`
    // now do more stuff
    this.anotherProperty = 'foo';
};
customObject2.prototype = Object.create(customObject.prototype);
    // inherit prototype but keep original safe

new customObject2();
```

---

Backwards compatible `Object.create`

```
function objectWithProto(proto) {
    var f;
    if (Object.create) return Object.create(proto);
    f = function () {};
    f.prototype = proto;
    return new f();
}
```

Comment: Do you have an alternative for the Object.create that is compatible with older browsers as well? Oh, hang on: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5199126/javascript-object-create-not-working-in-firefox

Comment: Thanks, this is the short solution I was looking for and it avoids simply extending `customObject`

Comment: @user2180613 But this is also extending customObject, it's just a different technique.

Comment: @bfavaretto iirc coffeescript uses this style with their `extend` keyword

Answer (score 0):

I think [this should answer your question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1646698/what-is-the-new-keyword-in-javascript). Basically, the new keyword is returning an object and not a function.

Comment: No it doesn't. I know very well what the keyword does, but I was wondering if there is a quick way to copy an object and have it remain "instantiatable".

Answer (score 0):

Why are you not using the same formula you used the first time? For example:

```
var customObject2 = function(){};
customObject2.prototype = new customObject();
customObject2.property = "modified value";
new customObject2(); // works!
```

All properties of `customObject` will be inherited by the instances of `customObject2` through the prototype chain.

Comment: I'm not looking for inheritance.