# JavaScript inheritance: member functions not inheriting?

Tags: javascript, oop, inheritance

This is driving me crazy. I'm about to break down and cry.

Here's my code that is NOT working:

```
// parent class: Shirt
var Shirt = function() {
    this.basePrice = 1;
}
Shirt.prototype.getPrice = function(){return this.basePrice};
Shirt.prototype.display = function(){
    $('ul#products').append('<li>Product: $' + this.getPrice() + '.00</li>');
};

// subclass: ExpensiveShirt inherits from Shirt
var ExpensiveShirt = function() {
    this.basePrice = 5;
};
ExpensiveShirt.prototype = Object.create(Shirt);


// make some objects and test them
var s = new Shirt();
s.display();               // this works
console.log(s.getPrice()); // this works

var e = new ExpensiveShirt();
e.display();               // this does not work!
console.log(e.getPrice()); // does not work
```

### [HERE IS THE JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/r4e2LLm7/)

Now, if I add these lines, then it works:

```
ExpensiveShirt.prototype.getPrice = Shirt.prototype.getPrice;
ExpensiveShirt.prototype.display = Shirt.prototype.display;
```

But according to this I shouldn't have to: [JavaScript inheritance with Object.create()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3079887/javascript-inheritance-with-object-create) 
And I really don't want to because that is bad programming. >:(

Comment: Do not mix presentation logic and data...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Object.create](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create) expects the prototype for the new object as its argument, not the constructor. Change your line to this, and it will work:

```
ExpensiveShirt.prototype = Object.create(Shirt.prototype);
```

Comment: errmerrgerrdddd thank you so much! my brain is not fully working today.

Answer (score 1):

As @Paulpro mentions, you need to use `Object.create` on `Shirt.prototype` and not `Shirt` for inheritance to work.

I usually use the following two functions to make my life easier when dealing with inheritance in JavaScript:

```js
var Shirt = defclass({
    constructor: function () {
        this.basePrice = 1;
    },
    getPrice: function () {
        return this.basePrice;
    },
    display: function () {
        alert("Product: $" + this.getPrice() + ".00");
    }
});

var ExpensiveShirt = extend(Shirt, {
    constructor: function () {
        this.basePrice = 5;
    }
});

var s = new Shirt;
var e = new ExpensiveShirt;

s.display();
e.display();

console.log(s.getPrice());
console.log(e.getPrice());
```

```html
<script>
function defclass(prototype) {
    var constructor = prototype.constructor;
    constructor.prototype = prototype;
    return constructor;
}

function extend(constructor, properties) {
    var prototype = Object.create(constructor.prototype);
    for (var key in properties) prototype[key] = properties[key];
    return defclass(prototype);
}
</script>
```

Hope that helps.