# Object.create() cant access variable inside function

Tags: javascript

I'm using below code.

```js
var emp = function employee(name, sal) {
  this.empname = name;
  this.sal = sal;
}

emp.prototype.getName = function() {
  return this.empname
};

var man = new emp("manish", 100);
console.log(man.getName()); //prints manish

var man1 = Object.create(emp);
man1.empname = "manish1";
console.log(man1.prototype.getName()); //prints undefined.
```

can some help me to understand why object create is printing undefined instead  manish1.

Comment: This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3079887/javascript-inheritance-with-object-create

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`new X()` creates a new object with constructor `X` and prototype `X.prototype`. `Object.create(X)` creates a new object with prototype `X` (and therefore constructor `X.constructor`).

So you need to call it with the *prototype* you want:

```
var man2 = Object.create(emp.prototype);   
man2.empname = "manish2";
console.log (man2.getName()); // prints manish2
```