# Crockford's Prototypal inheritance - Issues with nested objects

Tags: javascript, prototypal-inheritance

I've been reading "Javascript: The Good Parts" by Douglas Crockford - and while it's a bit extreme, I'm on board with a lot of what he has to say.

In chapter 3, he discusses objects and at one point lays out a pattern (also [found here](http://javascript.crockford.com/prototypal.html)) for simplifying & avoiding some of the confusion/issues that come with the use of the built-in "new" keyword.

```
if (typeof Object.create !== 'function') {
    Object.create = function (o) {
        function F() {}
        F.prototype = o;
        return new F();
    };
}
newObject = Object.create(oldObject);
```

So I've tried using this in a project I'm working on, and I noticed an issue when attempting to inherit from objects that are nested.  If I overwrite a value of a nested object inherited using this pattern, it overwrites the nested element all the way up the prototype chain.

Crockford's example is like the `flatObj` in the following example, which works well. The behaviour, however, is inconsistent with nested objects:

```
var flatObj = {
    firstname: "John",
    lastname: "Doe",
    age: 23
}
var person1 = Object.create(flatObj);

var nestObj = {
    sex: "female",
    info: {
        firstname: "Jane",
        lastname: "Dough",
        age: 32  
    }
}
var person2 = Object.create(nestObj);

var nestObj2 = {
    sex: "male",
    info: {
        firstname: "Arnold",
        lastname: "Schwarzenneger",
        age: 61  
    }
}
var person3 = {
    sex: "male"
}
person3.info = Object.create(nestObj2.info);

// now change the objects:
person1.age = 69;
person2.info.age = 96;
person3.info.age = 0;

// prototypes should not have changed:
flatObj.age // 23
nestObj.info.age // 96 ???
nestObj2.info.age // 61

// now delete properties:
delete person1.age;
delete person2.info.age;
delete person3.info.age;

// prototypes should not have changed:
flatObj.age // 23
nestObj.info.age // undefined ???
nestObj2.info.age // 61
```

(also on a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tM7R7/))

Am I doing something wrong, or is this a limitation of this pattern?

Comment: related: [JavaScript Object.create — inheriting nested properties](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3191103/1048572)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is no inconsistency. Just don't think of nested objects: a *direct* property of an object is always either on its prototype or an own property. It's irrelevant wheter the property value a primitive or an object.

So, when you do

```
var parent = {
    x: {a:0}
};
var child = Object.create(parent);
```

`child.x` will be referencing the same object as `parent.x` - that one `{a:0}` object. And when you change a property of it:

```
var prop_val = child.x; // == parent.x
prop_val.a = 1;
```

both will be affected. To change a "nested" property independently, you first will have to create an independent object:

```
child.x = {a:0};
child.x.a = 1;
parent.x.a; // still 0
```

What you can do is

```
child.x = Object.create(parent.x);
child.x.a = 1;
delete child.x.a; // (child.x).a == 0, because child.x inherits from parent.x
delete child.x; // (child).x.a == 0, because child inherits from parent
```

which means they are not absolutely independent - but still two different objects.

Comment: This clarifies things quite a bit - and I understand the issue now.  Thanks :)  because all objects are references... Duh.  Still less convenient this way.  Oh well.

Comment: *"a direct property of an object is always either on its prototype or an own property"* -  To me a direct property means an objects own property, and the ones in it's prototype chain could be called *indirect*. Can you explain what exactly do you mean by direct property, or what is an *indirect* property..?

Comment: @TJ I think I used the term "direct" to mean the opposite of "nested" here. A single level in a property chain so to say.

Answer (score 1):

I think what's happening is that when you create `person2`, the `sex` and `info` properties of it refer to those in `nestObj`. When you reference `person2.info`, since `person2` doesn't redefine the `info` property, it goes through to the prototype and modifies the object there.

It looks like the "right" way to do it is the way you build `person3`, so that the object has its own `info` object to modify and doesn't go up to the prototype.

I'm reading the book too (slowly), so I sympathize with you. :)

Answer (score 1):

I've changed the examples to give you a better demonstration of what is happening here. [<kbd>Demo</kbd>](http://jsbin.com/wufugofizo/edit?js,console)

First we create an object with three properties; A number, a string and an object with one property with a string value.

Then we create a second object from the first using `Object.create()`;

```js
var obj1 = { 
    num : 1,
    str : 'foo',
    obj : { less: 'more' }
};
var obj2 = Object.create( obj1 );

console.log( '[1] obj1:', obj1 );
console.log( '[1] obj2:', obj2 );
```

```
"[1] obj1:"
[object Object] {
  num: 1,
  obj: [object Object] {
    less: "more"
  },
  str: "foo"
}
"[1] obj2:"
[object Object] {
  num: 1,
  obj: [object Object] {
    less: "more"
  },
  str: "foo"
}
```

Looks good right? We have our first object and a second copied object.

Not so fast; Let's see what happens when we change some of the values on the first object.

```js
obj1.num = 3;
obj1.str = 'bar';
obj1.obj.less = 'less';

console.log( '[2] obj1:', obj1 );
console.log( '[2] obj2:', obj2 );
```

```
"[2] obj1:"
[object Object] {
  num: 3,
  obj: [object Object] {
    less: "less"
  },
  str: "bar"
}
"[2] obj2:"
[object Object] {
  num: 3,
  obj: [object Object] {
    less: "less"
  },
  str: "bar"
}
```

Now again we have our first object, with changes, and a copy of that object. What's happening here?

Let's check if the objects have their own properties.

```js
for( var prop in obj1 ) console.log( '[3] obj1.hasOwnProperty( ' + prop + ' ): ' + obj1.hasOwnProperty( prop ) );
for( var prop in obj2 ) console.log( '[3] obj2.hasOwnProperty( ' + prop + ' ): ' + obj2.hasOwnProperty( prop ) );
```

```
"[3] obj1.hasOwnProperty( num ): true"
"[3] obj1.hasOwnProperty( str ): true"
"[3] obj1.hasOwnProperty( obj ): true"
"[3] obj2.hasOwnProperty( num ): false"
"[3] obj2.hasOwnProperty( str ): false"
"[3] obj2.hasOwnProperty( obj ): false"
```

`obj1` has all of its own properties, just like we defined, but `obj2` doesn't.

What happens when we change some of `obj2`'s properties?

```js
obj2.num = 1;
obj2.str = 'baz';
obj2.obj.less = 'more';

console.log( '[4] obj1:', obj1 );
console.log( '[4] obj2:', obj2 );
for( var prop in obj1 ) console.log( '[4] obj1.hasOwnProperty( ' + prop + ' ): ' + obj1.hasOwnProperty( prop ) );
for( var prop in obj2 ) console.log( '[4] obj2.hasOwnProperty( ' + prop + ' ): ' + obj2.hasOwnProperty( prop ) );
```

```
"[4] obj1:"
[object Object] {
  num: 3,
  obj: [object Object] {
    less: "more"
  },
  str: "bar"
}
"[4] obj2:"
[object Object] {
  num: 1,
  obj: [object Object] {
    less: "more"
  },
  str: "baz"
}
"[4] obj1.hasOwnProperty( num ): true"
"[4] obj1.hasOwnProperty( str ): true"
"[4] obj1.hasOwnProperty( obj ): true"
"[4] obj2.hasOwnProperty( num ): true"
"[4] obj2.hasOwnProperty( str ): true"
"[4] obj2.hasOwnProperty( obj ): false"
```

So, `num` and `str` changed on `obj2` and not on `obj1` just like we wanted, but `obj1.obj.less` changed when it shouldn't have.

From the `hasOwnProperty()` checks we can see that, even though we changed `obj2.obj.less`, we didn't set `obj2.obj` first. This means that we are still referring to `obj1.obj.less`.

Let's create an object from `obj1.obj` and assign it to `obj2.obj` and see if that gives us what we're looking for.

```js
obj2.obj = Object.create( obj1.obj );

console.log( '[5] obj1:', obj1 );
console.log( '[5] obj2:', obj2 );
for( var prop in obj1 ) console.log( '[5] obj1.hasOwnProperty( ' + prop + ' ): ' + obj1.hasOwnProperty( prop ) );
for( var prop in obj2 ) console.log( '[5] obj2.hasOwnProperty( ' + prop + ' ): ' + obj2.hasOwnProperty( prop ) );
```

```
"[5] obj1:"
[object Object] {
  num: 3,
  obj: [object Object] {
    less: "more"
  },
  str: "bar"
}
"[5] obj2:"
[object Object] {
  num: 1,
  obj: [object Object] {
    less: "more"
  },
  str: "baz"
}
"[5] obj1.hasOwnProperty( num ): true"
"[5] obj1.hasOwnProperty( str ): true"
"[5] obj1.hasOwnProperty( obj ): true"
"[5] obj2.hasOwnProperty( num ): true"
"[5] obj2.hasOwnProperty( str ): true"
"[5] obj2.hasOwnProperty( obj ): true"
```

That's good, now `obj2` has its own `obj` property. Let's see what happens when we change `obj2.obj.less` now.

```js
obj2.obj.less = 'less';

console.log( '[6] obj1:', obj1 );
console.log( '[6] obj2:', obj2 );
```

```
"[6] obj1:"
[object Object] {
  num: 3,
  obj: [object Object] {
    less: "more"
  },
  str: "bar"
}
"[6] obj2:"
[object Object] {
  num: 1,
  obj: [object Object] {
    less: "less"
  },
  str: "baz"
}
```

So what this all tells us is that, if the property has not yet been changed on the created object, any `get` requests to the created object for that property will be forwarded to the original object.

The `set` request for `obj2.obj.less = 'more'` from the previous code block first requires a `get` request for `obj2.obj`, which doesn't exist in `obj2` at that point, so it forwards to `obj1.obj` and in turn `obj1.obj.less`.

Then finally when we read `obj2` again, we still haven't set `obj2.obj` so that `get` request will be forwarded to `obj1.obj` and return the setting that we had previously changed, causing the effect that changing a property of the second objects object child seems to change both, but really it is only actually changing the first.

---

You can use this function to return a new object completely separated from the original recursively.

[<kbd>Demo</kbd>](http://jsbin.com/pemeridimu/edit?js,console)

```js
var obj1 = { 
    num : 1,
    str : 'foo',
    obj : { less: 'more' }
};
var obj2 = separateObject( obj1 );

function separateObject( obj1 ) {

    var obj2 = Object.create( Object.getPrototypeOf( obj1 ) );
    for(var prop in obj1) {
        if( typeof obj1[prop] === "object" )
            obj2[prop] = separateObject( obj1[prop] );
        else
            obj2[prop] = obj1[prop];
    }

    return obj2;
}

console.log( '[1] obj1:', obj1 );
console.log( '[1] obj2:', obj2 );
for( var prop in obj1 ) console.log( '[1] obj1.hasOwnProperty( ' + prop + ' ): ' + obj1.hasOwnProperty( prop ) );
for( var prop in obj2 ) console.log( '[1] obj2.hasOwnProperty( ' + prop + ' ): ' + obj2.hasOwnProperty( prop ) );
```

```
"[1] obj1:"
[object Object] {
  num: 1,
  obj: [object Object] {
    less: "more"
  },
  str: "foo"
}
"[1] obj2:"
[object Object] {
  num: 1,
  obj: [object Object] {
    less: "more"
  },
  str: "foo"
}
"[1] obj1.hasOwnProperty( num ): true"
"[1] obj1.hasOwnProperty( str ): true"
"[1] obj1.hasOwnProperty( obj ): true"
"[1] obj2.hasOwnProperty( num ): true"
"[1] obj2.hasOwnProperty( str ): true"
"[1] obj2.hasOwnProperty( obj ): true"
```

Let's see what happens when we change some variables now.

```js
obj1.num = 3;
obj1.str = 'bar';
obj1.obj.less = 'less';

console.log( '[2] obj1:', obj1 );
console.log( '[2] obj2:', obj2 );
```

```
"[2] obj1:"
[object Object] {
  num: 3,
  obj: [object Object] {
    less: "less"
  },
  str: "bar"
}
"[2] obj2:"
[object Object] {
  num: 1,
  obj: [object Object] {
    less: "more"
  },
  str: "foo"
}
```

Everything works exactly the way you expected it to.

Comment: What console does `console.log` objects like that, without showing inheritance structures?

Comment: For `separateObject` I'd recommend `Object.create(Object.getPrototypeOf(obj1))`

Comment: I copied the output from JSBin's console. I just tried `Object.getPrototypeOf(obj1)` but it returned an empty object. Am I missing something? I

Comment: Of course it does, that's the point - `obj1` has an empty prototype and so should `obj2`. You'll need to fix the loop and do `for (var prop in obj1)` though.

Comment: I see what you're getting at now. I've updated my answer.