# How do you get inheritance working within JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, inheritance, prototype

I want constructor `Paper` to inherit constructor `View`. I've read that there needs to be a temporary constructor `new F()`, but the parent is modified along with the child class prototype in my code:

```
function View() {};
function Paper() {};

View.prototype = {
    location: {
        "city": "UK"
    }
}


function F() {};

F.prototype = View.prototype;
Paper.prototype = new F();
Paper.prototype.constructor = Paper;
```

So when I try to modify the `Paper`'s prototype:

```
Paper.prototype.location.city = "US";
```

I find the `View`'s prototype is modified too!:

```
var view = new View();
console.log(view.location); //US! not UK
```

So what's wrong with my code? How can I override the prototype without affecting the parent?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Crockford's Prototypal inheritance - Issues with nested objects](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10131052/crockfords-prototypal-inheritance-issues-with-nested-objects)

Answer (score 0):

Inheritance in JS is tricky, as you've discovered. Perhaps someone smarter than I can enlighten us on the technical specifics as to *why*, but a possible solution would be to use the [very tiny Base.js](http://dean.edwards.name/weblog/2006/03/base/) framework, courtesy of [Dead Edwards](http://dean.edwards.name).

**edit: I have restructured the original code to fit Dean Edward's framework.**

Inheritance will work properly once you master the syntax. Here's a possible solution based on your code:

```
var View = Base.extend({
    constructor: function(location) {
        if (location) {
            this.location = location;
        }
    },

    location: "UK",

    getLocation: function() {
        return this.location;
    }
});
```

And extending it:

```
var Paper = View.extend({
    location: "US"
});
```

And testing it:

```
var view = new View();
alert("The current location of the view is: " + view.getLocation());
var paper = new Paper();
alert("The location of the paper is: " + paper.getLocation());
alert("The current location of the view is: " + view.getLocation());
```

---

**Alternatively, the same result can be achieved with:**

```
var Paper = View.extend();
```

And testing:

```
var view = new View();
alert("The current location of the view is: " + view.getLocation());
var paper = new Paper("US");
alert("The location of the paper is: " + paper.getLocation());
alert("The current location of the view is: " + view.getLocation());
```

Both will produce three alerts:

```
The current location of the view is: UK
The location of the paper is: US
The current location of the view is: UK
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: Could you please adapt the framework to OP's question, instead of copying the examples from the linked page? I fear it won't work.

Comment: @Bergi Done, although I won't be able to test it myself until this afternoon.

Comment: Please test it somewhen, I believe this still will show the issue.

Comment: @Bergi Fixed! Hopefully this at least partially answers OP's question.