# Why don't nested objects in Javascript preserve their values?

Tags: javascript

I am running two tests to check how objects worked in javascript:

Tests one:

```js
//Method 1
var Player = {

  name: "",
  id: "",
  action: {
    action1: "",
    action2: "",
    action3: ""
  }
}

var player1 = Object.create(Player);
player1.name = " hack";
player1.id = 1;
player1.action.action1 = "aaa";
player1.action.action2 = "aaa";
player1.action.action3 = "aaa";
console.log(JSON.stringify(player1.action));

var player2 = Object.create(Player);
player2.name = " Jason";
player2.id = 2;
player2.action.action1 = "bbb";
player2.action.action2 = "bbb";
player2.action.action3 = "bbb";

console.log(JSON.stringify(player2.action));
console.log(JSON.stringify(player1.action));
```

The result is:

```
          {"action1":"aaa","action2":"aaa","action3":"aaa"}
 VM174:29 {"action1":"bbb","action2":"bbb","action3":"bbb"}
 VM174:30 {"action1":"bbb","action2":"bbb","action3":"bbb"}
```

you can see the action object of player1 had been changed by creating player2.

What if I want the action object preserve it's value?

The only way I can think about is following:

```js
//Medthod 2 
var actionManager = {

  action1: "",
  action2: "",
  action3: ""

}
var Player = {

  name: "",
  id: "",
  action: null
}

var player1 = Object.create(Player);
var actions1 = Object.create(actionManager);
actions1.action1 = "aaa";
actions1.action2 = "aaa";
actions1.action3 = "aaa";

player1.name = " hack";
player1.id = 1;
player1.action = actions1;
console.log(JSON.stringify(player1));
var player2 = Object.create(Player);
player2.name = " Jason";
player2.id = 2;

var actions2 = Object.create(actionManager);
actions2.action1 = "bbb";
actions2.action2 = "bbb";
actions2.action3 = "bbb";

player2.action = actions2;
console.log(JSON.stringify(player2));
console.log(JSON.stringify(player1));
```

In this case the output is:

```
{"name":"hack","id":1,"action:{"action1":"aaa","action2":"aaa","action3":"aaa"}} 

{"name":" Jason","id":2,"action:{"action1":"bbb","action2":"bbb","action3":"bbb"}}

{"name":" hack","id":1,"action":{"action1":"aaa","action2":"aaa","action3":"aaa"}}
```

Is there any better way to use Method 1 but make the action object not being changed?

Comment: That is because the Object stored for `action` is for both elements the same. `Object.create(Player);` does (not fully technical correct explanation, but the same problem) not do a deep copy but a shallow copy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that both players share the same `Player` object as prototype. When one player alters fields in this object, they will be changed when looking in the other object too.

You can use constructor functions for this:

```
// constructor function
function Player () {
  this.name = "";
  this.id = "";
  this.action = {
    action1: "",
    action2: "",
    action3: ""
  };
}

var player1 = new Player();
player1.name = " hack";
player1.id = 1;
player1.action.action1 = "aaa";
player1.action.action2 = "aaa";
player1.action.action3 = "aaa";
console.log(JSON.stringify(player1.action));

var player2 = new Player();
player2.name = " Jason";
player2.id = 2;
player2.action.action1 = "bbb";
player2.action.action2 = "bbb";
player2.action.action3 = "bbb";

console.log(JSON.stringify(player2.action));
console.log(JSON.stringify(player1.action));
```

when you call `new Player()`, a new object is instantiated, and new properties like `name` and `id` are created for this object, and multiple instances of `Player` will not conflict with each other.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any better way to use Method 1 but make the action object not being changed?

Use a constructor function that initialises the `action` property for you, so that you don't have to write it out manually. You cannot avoid [needing them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10131052/crockfords-prototypal-inheritance-issues-with-nested-objects/), except you flatten them and put the `.action*`s directly on the player.

Answer (score 0):

Since When you substitute Array or Object in Javascript, Javascript makes Referencing to the Array/Object instead of Copying.
So when you do `player1.action.action1 = "aaa";` or `player2.action.action1 = "bbb";`, You are changing the Value of `Player`'s value. Since player1 or player2 are just pointing to `Player` Object.

> The Object.create() method creates a new object with the specified prototype object and properties.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create

which means you are creating a new object which has same reference to the Array/Object. Because even `Player` does not have Array as its property but a reference to the memory address of the Array/Object.So the new Object created by `Object.create()` also have just references.

If you check What the Player object has as well, You'd notice that its values had also changed.

```
console.log(Player)

action:
  action1: "bbb"
  action2: "bbb"
  action3: "bbb"
```

To avoid this. You need to deep copy the object when you use it as prototype.

```
//Method 1
var Player = {

  name: "",
  id: "",
  action: {
    action1: "",
    action2: "",
    action3: ""
  }
}

objectCreate = function(obj){
    return jQuery.extend(true, {},obj)
};

var player1 = objectCreate(Player);
player1.name = " hack";
player1.id = 1;
player1.action.action1 = "aaa";
player1.action.action2 = "aaa";
player1.action.action3 = "aaa";
console.log(JSON.stringify(player1.action));

var player2 = objectCreate(Player);
player2.name = " Jason";
player2.id = 2;
player2.action.action1 = "bbb";
player2.action.action2 = "bbb";
player2.action.action3 = "bbb";

console.log(JSON.stringify(player2));
console.log(JSON.stringify(player1));
console.log(Player)
```

You need jQuery though

```
objectCreate = function(obj){
    return jQuery.extend(true, {},obj)
};
```

this gives you perfect deep copied Object.
and the code above works as you expected.

see the jQuery.extend details here http://api.jquery.com/jquery.extend/

Answer (score 0):

What `Object.create` does is, it take an object as the input and copies all it's attributes to the new object. Now if a attribute points to a mutable value you would be able to mutate it using the newly created object. So, you can mutate the value of `Player.action` using any reference variable that points to it's value, `player1.action` and `player2.action` in your example.

And according you code `Player` should a class instead of an object. So, we can make it a constructor function (JS don't have classes but have object constructors) as follows.

```
//New Method 1
var Player = function() {
  this.name = "";
  this.id = "";
  this.action = {
    action1: "",
    action2: "",
    action3: ""
  };
};

var player1 = new Player();  // Create a new object using `Player` constructor function
player1.name = " hack";
player1.id = 1;
player1.action.action1 = "aaa";
player1.action.action2 = "aaa";
player1.action.action3 = "aaa";
console.log(JSON.stringify(player1.action));

var player2 = new Player();  // Create another object using `Player` constructor function
player2.name = " Jason";
player2.id = 2;
player2.action.action1 = "bbb";
player2.action.action2 = "bbb";
player2.action.action3 = "bbb";

console.log(JSON.stringify(player2.action));
console.log(JSON.stringify(player1.action));
```

Here objects `player1` and `player2` are created using constructor `Player`. The `new` keyword actually initiates a new object. In conventional OOP's sense you can say `player1` and `player2` objects of class `Player` have been created using the `new` keyword.

And the output would be

```
{"name":"hack","id":1,"action":{"action1":"aaa","action2":"aaa","action3":"aaa"}} 

{"name":" Jason","id":2,"action":{"action1":"bbb","action2":"bbb","action3":"bbb"}}

{"name":" hack","id":1,"action":{"action1":"aaa","action2":"aaa","action3":"aaa"}}
```