# Javascript module pattern - Object.create

Tags: javascript, module-pattern, revealing-module-pattern

A bit of confusion regarding what exactly is going on here.

given this simple code :

```
stuff = (function(){
    function extendFoo(bar)
    {
        $.extend(this.foo,bar);
    }
    this.foo = {};

    return { foo : foo, extendFoo: extendFoo};
})();
```

Following this simple operation :

```
zz = Object.create(stuff);
zz.extendFoo({bar:'bar'});
vv = Object.create(stuff); //foo is still extended(??)
```

So from what I realized, operations conducted on the returned object form Object.create still affect the prototype of that Object, So when you create a new object, his prototype is changed, thus resulting in a 'modified' version.

This seems wrong on a lot of levels, Can anyone explain what's going on here?

this behavior is not reproducible using the following pattern :

```
stuff = (function(){

    function setFoo(bar)
    {
        this.foo = bar;
    }
    var foo;

    return { foo : foo, setFoo: setFoo};

})();
```

So I suspect $.extend is to blame here.

Any input would be great!

Comment: Notice that `this.foo = {};` in that IEFE creates a global variable that you don't want, use `var foo = {}`. Doesn't make a difference for your problem though.

Comment: Does [Prototypal inheritance - Issues with nested objects](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10131052/1048572) answer your questions sufficiently? That you use a module pattern and setter methods might obscure the problem

Comment: You have two major errors in your code: the `foo` in `return { foo: foo,` is undefined, and the `this` in `this.foo = {}` is actually the `window` object. Please correct these

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem has nothing to do with the module pattern and everything to do with prototypes.

```
zz = Object.create(stuff)
```

creates a new object with `stuff` as its prototype.

```
vv = Object.create(stuff)
```

creates a new object with the same `stuff` object as its prototype.

Both `zz` and `vv` share the same prototype object, so if you modify the prototype object `stuff`, then changes will reflect in both derived objects `zz` and `vv`. It doesn't matter whether you're modifying the prototype via `$.extend` or other means, and it doesn't matter whether you're modifying the prototype via your derived object or your prototype.

In your code, the `foo` object is attached to the prototype, not to the derived objects `zz` and `vv`. When `extendFoo` is invoked on the derived object `zz`, it is modifying `foo` on the prototype, so changes to `foo` are shared by the derived objects.

In your second example, in `setFoo`

```
this.foo = bar;
```

what's happening is that you're setting the `foo` property on the derived object so now it overrides the prototype's `foo`. After you run `setFoo` on a derived object, that object's `foo` is no longer the prototype's `foo`. You can see this by running

```
zz = Object.create(stuff);
console.log(zz.hasOwnProperty('foo')); // false
zz.setFoo(bar);
console.log(zz.hasOwnProperty('foo')); // true
delete zz.foo;
console.print(zz.foo); // foo is the original foo, not null
console.log(zz.hasOwnProperty('foo')); // false
```

you'd actually get back your original `foo` instead of `null`.

The reason why `setFoo` works in the second case is because you are no longer modifying the prototype, so the changes are no longer shared between derived objects. With the original's

```
$.extend(this.foo,bar);
```

you're modifying the object `this.foo` in place and not overriding. You can also see this via `hasOwnProperty`

```
zz = Object.create(stuff);
console.log(zz.hasOwnProperty('foo')); // false
zz.extendFoo({bar:'bar'});
console.log(zz.hasOwnProperty('foo')); // false
```