# Node js extending inherited object (as enum)

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

It doesn't seem like you can extend a class object (in this case used as an enum) in Node.js. Example

**Foo**

```
class Foo {}
Foo.action = {};
Foo.action.jump = 1;
module.exports = Foo;
```

**Bar**

```
var Foo = require('./foo');
var Baz = require('./baz');

class Bar extends Foo { 
    constructor(){
        super();
        this.baz = new Baz();
    }   
}

Bar.action.stay = 2;
module.exports = Bar;
```

**Usage** (edit, it's used in a class)

```
var Bar = require('./bar');
class Baz {
    constructor(){
        console.log(Bar.action); //undefined
    }
}
module.exports = Baz;
```

I believe this is a cyclical dependency issue.

Comment: It's [working fine for me](https://jsfiddle.net/xbtngykb/). There's something weird going on here.

Comment: Your code works in my local machine too. which nodejs version You use?

Comment: @4castle `var b = new Bar(); console.log(b.action)`

Comment: @guest271314 That's going to be `undefined`, because there's a difference between `Bar.action` and `Bar.prototype.action`. This question is about just the inheritance of the "static" members.

Comment: @guest271314 user is trying to: `extend a class object` I think question is not correct

Comment: @jozenbasin, have You tried to require them like this: `require('./foo')`, `require('./bar')`  - because in my local machine I'm getting exception when I don't define correct path, maybe that is the solution to Your issue. But overall everything works as expected in nodejs env (v.7.4.0)

Comment: I added that the call is within class.

Comment: Being inside a class won't change the output. Please create a [mcve], so that we can reproduce the problem.

Comment: OK I replicated the issue to the smallest case possible. I think the issue is cyclical referencing. I guess I am screwed.

Comment: The only problem I can see with writing to `Bar.action.jump` is [that it thereby sets `Foo.action.jump` as well](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10131052/crockfords-prototypal-inheritance-issues-with-nested-objects/), being the *same* object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I believe this is a cyclical dependency issue.

Yes, the cyclical dependency between `Bar` and `Baz`, using *assignment* to the Common.js `module.exports`, makes `Bar` an empty object in the Baz.js module. The solution is to [use module properties only](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10872988/1048572). (Btw, this would've worked fine in declarative ES6 modules).