# Create a stand alone Javascript Object which inherits from parent but not from child to parent

Tags: javascript, inheritance

My goal is to have otherFoo inherit from foo, but then not inherit back up to the parent. I've tried a few angles with Object.create but it keeps inheriting back to the parent.

```
var foo = { "bar": {"data1":"02", "data2":"03"}, "otherBar":"09"};

var otherFoo = {};
otherFoo.bar = foo.bar;
otherFoo.bar.data1 = "04";
```

I want the end result to be

```
// foo = { "bar": {"data1":"02", "data2":"03"}};
// otherFoo = { "bar": {"data1":"04", "data2":"03"}};
```

Here is a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/lando2319/b99y9rfw/1/) for Convenience

Comment: You mean "copy" the object?

Comment: I just updated it, I'm intending to copy just `bar` not `otherBar`

Comment: References man. References. I'm to lazy can someone find the duplicate for this question.

Comment: Another way to accomplish the same goal: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new

Comment: Inherit? You mean like `otherFoo = Object.create(foo); otherFoo.bar = Object.create(foo.bar);`? Have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10131052/crockfords-prototypal-inheritance-issues-with-nested-objects/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you mean [Object.assign()](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Object/assign) ?

```js
let foo = { "bar": {"data1":"02", "data2":"03"}, "otherBar":"09"};

let otherFoo = Object.assign({}, foo);

foo.otherBar = 10;

console.log(foo);
console.log(otherFoo);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try using a class:

```
function template(data1) {
    this.data = { "bar": {"data1": typeof data1 !== 'undefined' ? data1: '02', "data2":"03"}};
}
var foo = new template();
var otherFoo = new template('04');
console.log(foo.data);
console.log(otherFoo.data);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can use Object spread operator:

```
var foo = { "bar": {"data1":"02", "data2":"03"}, "otherBar":"09"};

var { otherBar, ...bar } = foo
foo = bar
var fooBar = {
    bar: { ...foo.bar, data2: "04" }
}
```

Otherwise you need a deep clone of your object.

Comment: This isn't ES6, this is currently [a stage 3 ECMAScript proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-object-rest-spread), and is not implemented.

Answer (score 0):

Close to Talha's answer, but figured i'd just go ahead and post it (as it mimicks your example almost exactly above on what you want the data represented like)

```js
const bar = function(data){
  this.bar = data;
}

let foo = new bar({"data1":"02", "data2":"03"})
let otherFoo = new bar({"data1":"04", "data2":"03"})
console.log(foo)
console.log(otherFoo)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a function that can deep clone any object, including cyclical objects. It also maintains cyclical references as they are in the original object, without referencing any values from the original, except for values in the `prototype` chain:

```js
function clone (object, objects = new WeakMap()) {
  // this will omit copying primitives
  if (typeof object !== 'object' && typeof object !== 'function' || object === null) {
    return object;
  }

  if (objects.has(object)) {
    return objects.get(object);
  }

  const proto = Object.getPrototypeOf(object);
  const descriptors = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors(object);
  const copy = typeof object === 'function'
    ? object.call.bind(object)
    : Object.create(proto);

  objects.set(object, copy);

  Object.values(descriptors).forEach(descriptor => {
    if ('value' in descriptor) {
      descriptor.value = clone(descriptor.value, objects);
    }
  });

  return Object.defineProperties(copy, descriptors);
}

let foo = { bar: { data1: '02', data2: '03' }, otherBar: '09' };

class Test {
  constructor (...args) { this.args = args; }
  cool () { return 'feature'; }
}

foo.bar.foo = foo;
foo.bar.bar = foo.bar;
foo.test = new Test('foo', 'bar');
foo.bar.test = foo.test;
foo.bar.func = () => 'func';

console.log(foo);

var otherFoo = clone(foo);

// everything copies as expected
console.log(otherFoo);
console.log(otherFoo.test instanceof Test);
console.log(otherFoo.bar.func() === 'func');
console.log(typeof otherFoo.bar.func === 'function');
// nothing references the original object
console.log(foo !== otherFoo);
console.log(foo.bar !== otherFoo.bar);
console.log(foo.test !== otherFoo.test);
console.log(foo.bar.func !== otherFoo.bar.func);
// doesn't copy prototypes
console.log(foo.test.cool === otherFoo.test.cool);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{max-height:100%!important}
```