# Using Javascript prototype, how to get an instance property from another property of the same instance?

Tags: javascript, prototype, javascript-objects, prototypal-inheritance

Using Javascript prototype, how to get an instance property from another property of the same instance?

I am trying to call the `Main.prototype.a` methods from the `Main.prototype.b` methods.

I managed to solve this by adding an `init` method on `Main.prototype.b` that accepts an `instance` variable and saves it as `this.instance` which could later be used to refer to the instance in the other methods.

And then calling the `init` method from the `Main` constructor function while passing `this` as the variable but I feel like I am missing a different more elegant and simple solution.

This is just a very simplified example of what I am trying to understand:

```
var Main = function(){}

Main.prototype.a = {
    value: 1,
    one: function(){
        this.value++;
        console.log("added 1", this.value);
    },
    two: function(){
        this.value--;
        console.log("reduced 1", this.value);
    },
    three: function(){
        this.value+=10;
        console.log("added 10", this.value);
    }
}

Main.prototype.b = {
    one: function(){
        //call Main.prototype.a.one
    },
    two: function(){
        //call Main.prototype.a.two
    },
    three: function(){
        //call Main.prototype.a.three
    },
    getValue: function(){
        //return Main.prototype.a.variable
    }
}

var main = new Main();
```

Thank you for taking the time to read and to all who offers solutions in advance!

Comment: [Don't put objects in inherited prototype properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10131052/crockfords-prototypal-inheritance-issues-with-nested-objects/) - especially not that `value`. You'll want to initialise it in the constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply:

```js
var Main = function(){}

Main.prototype.a = {
    value: 1,
    one: function(){
        this.value++;
        console.log("added 1", this.value);
    },
    two: function(){
        this.value--;
        console.log("reduced 1", this.value);
    },
    three: function(){
        this.value+=10;
        console.log("added 10", this.value);
    }
}

Main.prototype.b = {
    one: function(){
      Main.prototype.a.one();
    },
    two: function(){
        //call Main.prototype.a.two
    },
    three: function(){
        //call Main.prototype.a.three
    },
    getValue: function(){
        //return Main.prototype.a.variable
    }
}

var main = new Main();
main.b.one();
main.b.one();
```