# Prototypal inheritance with nested objects

Tags: javascript, prototypal-inheritance

I'm trying to get my head around prototype inheritance in Javascript. I think I got the basic concept, but when I was playing around with this I ran into the following which still has me puzzled.

There is a very similar question and answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3191103/javascript-object-create-inheriting-nested-properties) but it doesn't fully answer **why** this is happening, at least not for me.

I create a new object like this:

```
var User = {
  username: "",
  name: {
    first: "",
    last: ""
  }
}
```

Next I create two "instances" of that object:

```
var user1 = Object.create(User);
var user2 = Object.create(User);
```

Now I set the name property like so:

```
user1.name = { first: "John", last: "Jackson"}
user2.name = { first: "James", last: "Jameson"}
```

Now I do

`alert(user1.name.first) \\ -> John`
`alert(user2.name.first) \\ -> James`

All as expected. So far so good.

However, if I set the name.first property like this:

```
user1.name.first = "John";
user2.name.first = "James";
```

and I get

```
alert(user1.name.first) \\ -> James
alert(user2.name.first) \\ -> James
```

Clearly now the property is being set on the prototype object `User` (or rather the contained `name` object) instead of overriding it in the current object `user1`. Why does that occur?

Further if I do

```
user1.name.middle = "Mortimer"
```

I can now do

```
alert(User.name.middle) // -> Mortimer
```

which is not what I would expect. Generally, whenever a property is set on a derived object, that object either already has that property as an `ownProperty` in which case the value is simply assigned, or the property is newly created as an `ownProperty` on the derived object, overriding the prototype property. Just like happens when I assign to `user1.name`.

So why does assigning to an object contained in the prototype object cause such (at least to me) unexpected and counter-intuitive behavior?

The way I understand it, when the assignment is made the first check is to see if `user1` has an `ownProperty` called `name`, which it doesn't. If this were a read operation the `prototype` property would now be looked up and `User` checked to see if it has `ownProperty` `name`. But since this is a set operation why walk the prototype chain when usually a missing ownProperty is simply created?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *But since this is a set operation why walk the prototype chain when usually a missing ownProperty is simply created?*

When you say `user1.name.first = "John"`, the `user1.name` part has to be resolved before the `.first` property can be retrieved or set. And in your example the `user1.name` part only exists on the prototype object, so it is *that* object whose `.first` property you are setting.

Similarly, when you say `user1.name.middle = "Mortimer"`, again the `user1.name` part resolves to the nested object from the prototype, so then you create a `.middle` property on *that* object, which is why `User.name.middle` also returns `"Mortimer"`.

If you said `user1.name.first` and `user1.name` could not be resolved (on the current object or in its prototype chain) then you'd have a `TypeError: Cannot set property 'first' of undefined`. (You can try that concept with your existing code by saying `user1.address.street = "something"` - you'd get the `TypeError`, because `user1.address` doesn't exist on `user1` or its prototype chain.)

Answer (score 1):

Since you've already read over similar questions and answers and still seem to be having trouble understanding the behavior, I'll try to make my explanation as clear as possible. Here is where I think you are going wrong (emphasis mine):

> Generally, **whenever a property is set on a derived object**, that object either already has that property as an ownProperty in which case the value is simply assigned, or the property is newly created as an ownProperty on the derived object, overriding the prototype property. Just like happens when I assign to user1.name.

The problem here is that you assume that `user.name.first` counts as "a property  . . . set on a derived object" (an instance of `User`). However, this is simply not the case. In JavaScript, inheritance of properties is only shallow (a single layer deep). `user.name` is just an object value shared by reference through the prototype, so modifications to it from one place are reflected everywhere.

Think of `user1.name` and `user2.name` like `firstReference` and `secondReference` in the following example snippet, and hopefully the behavior will seem a bit clearer to you.

```js
var User = {
  username: "",
  name: {
    first: "",
    last: ""
  }
}

var firstReference = User.name
var secondReference = User.name

firstReference.name.first = 'First!'

console.log(secondReference.name) //=> 'First!' (logical and expected result)
```

Answer (score 0):

The `Object.create` method creates an object using the first parameter as a prototype, and the second, optional, parameter is an additional object of own properties.

I think the problem here is that `name` is, by definition, in the prototype, and so not an own property.

If you want separate properties, then you should use the second parameter. The prototype is where you store methods and shared properties.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create

has more details.

The key is that you want both prototype and own properties.