# What's the difference between these two inheritance strategies?

Tags: javascript, inheritance, prototype

I think they are equivalent but I'm not sure:

```
var __extends = function(child, parent) { 
    for (var key in parent) { 
        if (__hasProp.call(parent, key)) child[key] = parent[key]; 
    }
    function ctor() { 
        this.constructor = child; 
    } 
    ctor.prototype = parent.prototype; 
    child.prototype = new ctor; 
    child.__super__ = parent.prototype;
    return child; 
};
```

And

```
var __extends = function(child, parent) { 
    for (var key in parent) { 
        if (__hasProp.call(parent, key)) child[key] = parent[key]; 
    }
    child.prototype = parent.prototype;
    child.prototype.constructor = child;
    child.__super__ = parent.prototype;
    return child; 
};
```

Comment: And you pass in two functions???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both functions extend the `child` (function) object with all properties of the `parent` object, and they set the `__super__` property. Then the differences begin:

```
function ctor() { 
    this.constructor = child; 
} 
ctor.prototype = parent.prototype; 
child.prototype = new ctor;
```

This code creates a prototype object for `child` which inherits from `parent.prototype`. It is an [old version](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2709612/1048572) of what [`Object.create()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create) does. This is the classical JavaScript inheritance pattern.

```
child.prototype = parent.prototype;
child.prototype.constructor = child;
child.__super__ = parent.prototype;
```

This code is crap. It sets the `child`'s prototype object to `parent.prototype`, but forgets right in the next line that now both properties point to the same object (`child.prototype === parent.prototype`). Therefore, `parent.prototype.constructor === child` and `child.__super__ === child.protoype` - urgh.