# Prototypal Inheritance in JavaScript...Can I call a "super" equivalent?

Tags: javascript, inheritance, prototype

I am building an object oriented library in javascript using prototypal inheritance. Similarly to Java and .NET, all of my objects/prototypes will inherit the "Object" object/prototype. I want to know if it is possible to call super object/prototype functions from derived ones?

Consider the following code exmaple:

```
function Object() {
    this.DoAction = function() {
    };
};

function CustomObject() {
    this.DoAction = function() {
        super.DoAction();    //How do I do this in JavaScript?
    };
};
```

Comment: http://www.crockford.com/javascript/inheritance.html :)

Comment: My Pref `Object.create`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2709612/using-object-create-instead-of-new

Comment: Not really. Super does not work in a prototypal system.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

JavaScript does not have the direct equivalent of `super`.

A workaround could be to save the method on the prototype before overriding it, like:

```
function CustomObject() {
    this._super_DoAction = this.DoAction;
    this.DoAction = function() {
        this._super_DoAction(); 
    };
};
```

If you are able to use ES5 features, you can use `Object.getPrototypeOf` to get the method from the prototype, and then `apply` to execute it with the current object as `this`:

```
function CustomObject(){
    this.DoAction=function() {
        Object.getPrototypeOf(this).DoAction.apply(this, []);
    };
}
```