# SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'create' - IE9

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-9

This code snippet is to create new object, it works fine on other browsers but IE 9.

```
function Item(no, name, qty, lineNo) {¬
       this.no = no;¬
       this.name = name;¬
       this.qty = qty;¬
       this.lineNo = lineNo;¬
     }¬
     Item.prototype = Object.create(null);¬ // error this line
```

How can I fix this ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2709612/using-object-create-instead-of-new this will help you.... Object.create() is not supported in some of thw browsers

Answer (score 0):

According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ff925952(v=vs.94).aspx)

Object.create:

Supported in the following document modes: Internet Explorer 9 standards, 
Internet Explorer 10 standards, and Internet Explorer 11 standards. Not 
supported in the following document modes: Quirks, Internet 
Explorer 6 standards, Internet Explorer 7 standards, Internet Explorer 8 standards.

So as you using `IE9` check the compatibility mode if it is set to `standards` or `Quirks`.