# Passing arguments when using Object.create as opposed to new

Tags: javascript, object-create

This question isn't a duplicate of [Using "Object.create" instead of "new"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2709612/using-object-create-instead-of-new).  The thread in question doesn't focus on passing arguments correctly when using `Object.create`

---

I am curious as to how I would go about initializing objects using `Object.create` as opposed to `new`.  Here is my code so far:

```
function Human(eyes) {
    this.eyes = eyes || false;
}

Human.prototype.hasEyes = function() {
    return this.eyes;
}

function Male(name) {
    this.name = name || "No name";
}

Male.prototype = new Human(true); //passing true to the Human constructor

var Sethen = new Male("Sethen");

console.log(Sethen.hasEyes());
```

As you can see above, the `Male.prototype = new Human(true);` creates a new object with true.  When the `hasEyes()` function is run, this logs true as expected.

So, my question is.. using `Object.create` how would I go about doing this the same way passing a `true` parameter??

Comment: Dup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2709612/using-object-create-instead-of-new

Comment: This isn't an exact duplicate by the way, the thread in question focuses on using `Object.create` over `new` where I am trying to focus on passing arguments with each of them, something that thread doesn't cover.

Comment: you could do this like this: http://jsbin.com/umodef/1/edit

Comment: @Glutamat I guess I am not sure how this applies to the question.  Did you see the answer I provided?  This seems to be the way to go about this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You must call the constructor using `Object.call(this)` and then pass your arguments.

```
function Human(eyes, phrase) {
    this.eyes = eyes || false;
    this.phrase = phrase;
}

Human.prototype.hasEyes = function() {
    return this.eyes;
}

Human.prototype.sayPhrase = function() {
    return this.phrase;
}

function Male(name) {
    Human.call(this, true, "Something to say"); //notice the call and the arguments
    this.name = name || "No name";
}

Male.prototype = Object.create(Human.prototype);

var Sethen = new Male("Sethen");

console.log(Sethen.hasEyes());
console.log(Sethen.sayPhrase());

console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(Sethen));
```

This works and now the object `Male` has the properties of `eyes` and `phrase`

Comment: Thanks finally found a post that does proper inheritance in JavaScript :)

Answer (score 0):

is this give some clue about prototype inheritance model.

```
const Human = {
    constructor: function (eyes) {
        this.eyes = eyes || false;
    },
    hasEyes: function () {
        return this.eyes;
    }
};

let Male = Object.create(Human);

Male.constructor = function (name) {
    this.name = name || "No name";
    return Human.constructor.call(this, "true");
};

let Sethen = Object.create(Male);
Sethen.constructor = function() {
    return Male.constructor.call(this, 'Sethen');
};

Sethen.constructor();

console.log(Sethen.hasEyes());
console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(Sethen));
```