# What is differential inheritance in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, prototype

This [answer on `Object.create()` method in JavaScript in SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2709811/1527084) talks about *differential inheritance*. It goes on to say this :

> This methods allows you to easily implement differential inheritance,
>   where objects can directly inherit from other objects.

As far as I know JavaScript always allowed objects to directly inherit from other objects via prototypal inheritance. There is no concept of a *class* in JavaScript. So what does *differential inheritance* really mean and why is it called so?

P.S: I had dropped a comment on that answer some time back but I didn't receive any replies. So wanted to check with the larger and awesome community of SO JavaScript users.

Comment: Apparently, ["differential inheritance"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_inheritance) is just another way of saying "prototypal inheritance".

Comment: [This may describe better.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Differential_inheritance_in_JavaScript)

Comment: @SheikhHeera: Actually it doesn't, because the example given there does not work and is at least misleading.

Comment: @Bergi, Misleading ? Then what is the right-leading, any example of your own or reference ?

Comment: @SheikhHeera: Working on it :-) The `Object.prototype.clone` method should be a straight `return Object.create(this)`, then the example at MDN makes more sense. Edit: Ah, [this old version](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Differential_inheritance_in_JavaScript$revision/70198) was better.

Answer (score 11):

As the other commenters and the articles they've linked already suggested, *differential inheritance* is "just" the normal, known prototypical inheritance.

Yet by using the term *differential inheritance* you focus on a more pure pattern than it is known in JavaScript (though quite common in other prototypical languages like Self, NewtonScript or Io). Unlike the pseudo-classical pattern, there are no constructors with `new` usage at all. Instead, by using `Object.create` you create a new object inheriting from the target object in one step, and then you create the necessary instance properties (only those that are *different*) manually (not with a constructor). It's not unusual to inherit from an object that you would consider to be an *instance* otherwise, instead of from a dedicated prototype object.

```
var object = Object.prototype;

// a Person constructor and a Person.prototype method would be more familiar
var person = Object.create(object);
person.greet = function() { 
    console.log("Hi, I'm "+this.firstName+" "+this.lastName);
};

// as would new Person("John", "Doe");
var jo = Object.create(person);
jo.firstName = "John";
jo.lastName = "Doe";

// but what now? We stay with "simple" Object.create here
var ja = Object.create(jo);
ja.firstName = "Jane";

jo.greet();
ja.greet();
```

As you can see creating a Jane is simple, but we would have to break with the `new Constructor()` pattern if we had used it. That's why some JS gurus are advocating to use the pure pattern everywhere (so that you understand better what's going on) and are happy to have been given `Object.create` with EcmaScript 5.

Still, using the constructor pattern and building conventional class hierarchies is common and helpful, and indeed possible in prototypical languages. Io for example will call an `init` method (if existing) everytime you `clone` an object, and in above example we could have used one as well which would have made the initialisation of Joe simpler:

```
person.init = function(f, l) {
   this.firstName = f; this.lastName = l; return this;
}
var jo = Object.create(person).init("John", "Doe");
```

There is definitely no straight line to distinguish between *differential* and *prototypical* inheritance.

Comment: Instead of using `init()`, `Object.create()` has a second argument: the properties.  This can be used to populate the instance properties more elegantly, as described in the OP link (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2709612/using-object-create-instead-of-new/2709811#2709811).

Comment: @Steve: More elegantly? I doubt so, as it takes *property descriptors* not simple properties. That includes a lot of boilerplate if you want "normal" (writeable, enumerable) properties.