# Object.create not working as expected

Tags: javascript

I'm not sure why this code is not working. I'm trying to use `Object.create();` instead `new`

```
var Car = function() {
   console.log('Car Consctructor');
};

Car.prototype.color = 'red';

var bmw = Object.create(Car);

console.log(bmw.color); //Doesn't log red - ??
```

Comment: I found that out, modified question. Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using "Object.create" instead of "new"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2709612/using-object-create-instead-of-new)

Comment: As bergi's link shows is that if you want to use Object.create with constructor functions you usually use it to set up inheritance. The way you use it now makes no sense. http://stackoverflow.com/a/16063711/1641941

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Car` is a function, [`Object.create()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create) expects a prototype.

```
var bmw = Object.create(Car.prototype);
```

Comment: Thanks - also it doesn't invoke constructor?

Comment: @RuntimeException Nope. If you do want it to call `Car`, then you'll want to use `new Car()` rather than `Object.create()`.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to pass the `prototype` to `Object.create`

```
var bmw = Object.create(Car.prototype);
```

Refer : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create