# Javascript Object.Create() not having default values

Tags: javascript, object, default

Resources I've read

> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create

> [Object.create not working as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18869325/5437621)

I have a simple script

```
const defaults = {
    allowInputStyleChange: true
};

var entry = Object.create(defaults);

console.log(JSON.stringify(defaults));
console.log(JSON.stringify(entry));
```

This results in

```
{"allowInputStyleChange":true}
{}
```

I was expecting

```
{"allowInputStyleChange":true}
{"allowInputStyleChange":true}
```

Am I understanding how to implement it wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Object.create()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create) creates a new object with the passing object's prototype.

[`JSON.stringify()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) serializes the own enumerable properties of the object. Since, `entry` does not have it's own property, it returns `{}`

To get the properties of `defaults` included in the *JSONString*, you can use [`Object.assign()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign):

```js
const defaults = {
    allowInputStyleChange: true
};

var entry = Object.assign({}, defaults);

console.log(JSON.stringify(defaults));
console.log(JSON.stringify(entry));
```

Answer (score 1):

However, if you do:

```
console.log(entry.allowInputStyleChange); // true
console.log(entry.hasOwnProperty('allowInputStyleChange')); // false
```

The problem you have is that `JSON.stringify` only shows the enumerable own property of an object.

So `Object.create` is working according to what you're expecting, it's just that `JSON.stringify` does not show the prototype