# Can javascript constructor function and object.create be combined?

Tags: javascript, constructor, new-operator, object-create

**Update**

If this is not possible, please feel free to provide an answer explaining why.  I'd be happy to mark as it accepted.

---

I'd like to slightly simplify the following code (two steps for an object "declaration", I'd like to have one):

```
var Masher = function(opts) {
    this._name  = opts.name;
};

Masher.prototype = Object.create(Object.prototype, {
    _name:  { writable: true },
    name:  { get: function() { return this._name;  }}
});

// Note: (new Masher({name: 'bar'})).name == 'bar'
```

I would to create the entire function prototype in one shot with the constructor function appearing somewhere in the Object.create.  Perhaps, something like this:

```
var Basher = Object.create(Function.prototype, {
    _name:  { writable: true },
    name:  { get: function() { return this._name;  }},
    constructor: { value: function(opts) { this._name = opts.name; }}
});
```

However, when I call `new Basher()`, I get: 'TypeError: object is not a function'.

Although I realize I could do this with syntactic sugar (a helper library), my goals here are to keep things as simple as possible and pick up some understanding of the JS object, prototype, constructor internals.  I've tried to read as much on this as possible: [SO related questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2709612/using-object-create-instead-of-new), [Crockford](http://javascript.crockford.com/prototypal.html), [Ben Nadel](http://www.bennadel.com/?site-photo=557), [Joost Diepenmaat](http://zeekat.nl/articles/constructors-considered-mildly-confusing.html).

Perhaps I haven't found the correct formulation, or I'm fighting the design philosophy of Object.create, or the language doesn't allow this. Perhaps, this is really just a stylistic thing, and therefore, a conceit.

Of course, I can live with the two step process (Masher).  There's something about packaging it all in one shot that feels right (Basher).

Is there a way to do this? Thanks.

Comment: No, you cannot. You need to create two separate objects: the constructor function and the prototype object.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to use the class-based approach where you can call a constructor function with `new`, you will always have two parts:

- The constructor function itself (to initialise instances)
- The prototype object (for shared properties)

If you don't want to drop the prototype entirely, there is no JavaScript syntax to do both the function creation and the prototype setup in one go (apart from the new ES6 `class` syntax, of course) while still maintaining the `.prototype` link from the function to the prototype object. Of course, a trivial helper function (doesn't need to be a complete library) would do:

```
function Class(p) {
    return (p.constructor.prototype = p).constructor;
}
var Casher = Class({
    constructor: function(opt) { this._name = opt.name },
    get name() { return this._name }
});
var foo = new Casher({name:'bar'});
```

This patterns doesn't really have a lot to do with `Object.create` at all (except you want your prototype inherit from another one).

So yes, maybe you are trying to fight the philosophy of `Object.create`, which is to use only objects and derive other objects from these (read the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prototype-based_programming) on it and make sure to check out some example from languages other than JS). You would not have a constructor, and not a `new` operator - rather you'd call a `create` method on your object:

```
var Proto = { // some helper methods (usually native in more prototype-focused languages)
    clone: function() {
        return Object.create(this);
    },
    create: function(opt) {
        var derived = this.clone();
        derived.init(opt);
        return derived;
    },
    init: function(opt) {
        Object.getOwnPropertyNames(opt).forEach(function(p) {
            Object.defineProperty(this, p, Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(opt, p));
        }, this);
    }
};

var Pasher = Proto.create({ // "subclass" Proto
    init: function(opt) {
        if ("name" in opt) this._name = opt.name;
    },
    _name: "",
    get name() { return this._name; }
});
var foo = Pasher.create({name:'bar'});
```

Comment: thank you. The ES6 class syntax pointer helps. I like the Class suggestion, although its missing the property descriptors, so not sure I would use it. I read the Wikipedia article. Nothing in there motivated why object creation in a prototype-based language need not have constructors, let alone well-formed syntax for constructors. After looking over the new ES6 class definition, to me it looks like this is a matter of language evolution - borrowing good ideas from other langs. My experience w/ Self, Lisp, C++, Java & C# make me want an orderly, explicit class definition. Guess I wait.

Answer (score 0):

`Object.create()` returns an *object*, not a function, with a specific prototypal inheritance chain defined.

```
var Basher = Object.create(Function.prototype, {
    _name:  { writable: true },
    name:  { get: function() { return this._name;  }},
    constructor: { value: function(opts) { this._name = opts.name; }}
});
> undefined
Basher
> Object {_name: undefined, name: (...)}_name: undefinedconstructor: function (opts) { this._name = opts.name; }name: (...)get name: function () { return this._name;  }__proto__: function Empty() {}
> typeof Basher
"object"
```

You can, however, combine `Object.create()` and constructor functions to let you reuse object literals as APIs, which makes the code look a bit cleaner:

```
var basherAPI = {
    name: function () {
        return this._name;
    }
};

function Basher(name) {
    var inst = Object.create(basherAPI);
    // assign instance *state* here; the API is
    // reusable but each object needs its own state
    inst._name = name;
    return inst;
}

var basher = new Basher('Tom');
basher.name() // Tom
```

EDIT: In this case, using the `new` keyword is purely convention; it has NO bearing on what happens within the constructor function. One could also write: `var basher = Basher('Tom');`.

Comment: Having Basher starting with a capital B could confuse other programmers to think they can inherit from it but actually can't. As it is a factory function it may be better not to have it start with a capital

Comment: Yes, excellent point. Inheritance may still be achieved with `Object.create()` though: `Object.create(basher)`. Perhaps renaming `Bahser` as `basherFactory` would be an even better approach.

Comment: @NicholasCloud, I appreciate the effort. That said, I'm aware that I can finese this through other functions and make it look like one line. In addition, I like the 'new' operator as it signals object creation to someone reading the code. Adding Factory to the function name would indeed provide a similar signal. Not going for the Factory pattern here, however.

Answer (score 0):

I'm putting an answer in here, but I'm not sure this fully answers my question, so I won't be marking it as *the* answer as I don't believe I completely understand this part of the JS language.

The closest I believe I can get to this is the following:

```
var Lasher;

(Lasher = function (opts) {
    this._name = opts.name;
}).prototype = Object.create(Object.prototype, {
    _name:  { writable: true },
    name:  { get: function() { return this._name;  }},
});
```

This formulation exposes part of what is going on, something to which @Bergi alluded, albeit briefly.  First, note that it does not answer my question as it still requires two steps (Variable declaration and then Value assignment).  It does get to the heart of my stylistic issue, which is to co-locate all of the object's declaration code. It does this by capturing the anonymous function definition (constructor) in Lasher, then referencing the `prototype` property in order to assign it the prototype object (the rest of the "class" declaration).

Although grouped together as one computational unit, visually it's harder to parse and fairly ugly, quite frankly.  Also, the anonymous function might even capture Lasher in its scope (I'm not sure).

Incidentally, I tried this flawed approach. It's one statement, although still a bit ugly:

```
(function Crasher(opts) {
    this._name = opts.name;
}).prototype = Object.create(Object.prototype, {
    _name:  { writable: true },
    name:  { get: function() { return this._name;  }},
});
```

Too bad it doesn't work. Crasher is scoped to the first `()` and doesn't live in the outer scope, which is why the earlier code had to declare Crasher as a variable in order to capture the anonymous function.

The thing is, Lasher is not really simpler than Masher (above) from a line count or readability perspective.  So, the original formulation stands as the best (so far).

Also, although I understand why `Object.create` cannot be used as it creates an Object, I guess I don't understand how the internal JS interpreter creates functions vs. Objects.  What I mean is, a Function is an Object, but I guess there's no way to create a function that can be returned directly from `Object.create`.  That's the primary problem.

In addition, whatever is going on inside of the prototype assignment and the constructor assignment within that, adding a constructor property in the Object.create doesn't work.  We can see that with this bit of code:

```
var Masher = function(){ console.log("default");};

Masher.prototype = Object.create(Object.prototype, {
    _name:  { writable: true },
    name:  { get: function() { return this._name;  }},
    constructor: { value: function(opts) {
        console.log("ctor");
        this._name  = opts.name;
    return this;
    }}
});
// "new Masher()" outputs:
// default
// undefined
```

So, if I understand some of this correctly, function creation and prototype creation on top of that have some deep relationships within the JS interpreter/compiler and the language does not provide a means to do what I am trying to do.