# difference between {} and function() {} for classes

Tags: javascript

In Javascript, I can create a "class" like this:

```
var MyClass = function(){
    return this;
};

var myClassInstance = new MyClass();
```

What is the difference between doing the above and doing this:

```
var MyClass = {};

var myClassInstance = Object.create(MyClass);
```

Is there any reason to use one over the other?

Comment: Dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2709612/using-object-create-instead-of-new or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4166616/understanding-the-difference-between-object-create-and-new-somefunction-in-j?

Comment: it means you are dealing with objects .;)

Comment: You will see the difference if you put some initialization logic inside the constructor function.

Comment: One reason is that when using the first style, using a function, `myClassInstance instanceof MyClass` returns true.

Comment: @forgivenson: As does `MyClass.isPrototypeOf(myClassInstance)` when using second style. But Felix is right, the second pattern "lacks" an initialisation *function*