# Literal instance creation behavior varies

Tags: javascript, object, object-literal

I have object literal within that i have another literal .
The parent instances are setting the values fine, but not the inner one.
I am confused with this behavior.
Why the behavior of object literal is different ?

here is the http://jsfiddle.net/Lq6frf76/

```
var vehicle={
    tires : 0,
    seats : { 
        total :0  
    }
}


var Car = Object.create(vehicle);
Car.tires=4;
Car.seats.total = 4 ;

var bike = Object.create(vehicle);
bike.tires=2;
bike.seats.total = 2 ;




console.log(Car.tires);     --->> it is not overwritten not consistent 
console.log(Car.seats.total); -->> it is overwritten here 

console.log(bike.tires);
console.log(bike.seats.total);
```

[image]

This is not a duplicate question

1. I knew the alternatives
2. I knew inner literal will override I saw lot of examples
3. What I don't know why the `same behavior is not repeated for the parent object` or in other words

   **why car.tires value is showing correctly instead of overwritten in my example**

Comment: no it does not for me

Comment: I see your problem now. The `Car.seats.total` seems not to have been set. That's not actually the problem: the problem is that `bike.seats` is overwriting `Car.seats`.

Comment: yes exactly that is my question why it is overwriting?

Comment: @naathon you have it explained here http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2184-object-create-improves-constructor-based-inheritance-in-javascript-it-doesn-t-replace-it.htm (an ok article to get an idea) and for better technical explanations see here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create

Comment: Good to read: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12705137/383904 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/6571266/383904

Comment: `child.seats` always refers to `vehicle.seats`. You're sharing one instance of `vehicle.seats` between all your child objects. You are inheriting an object *reference*. Whereas setting `Car.tires` does so on the new `Car` object you've created. (Not a duplicate Q. btw.)

Comment: (Not of the Q. noted above, anyhow.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit:** Added some more at the end and made a correction

I feel like we need to put down an answer here.  I apologize if this is bad etiquette (and if this is the wrong answer). Please let me know.

The way prototypical inheritance works in javascript:
When you **read** a property of an object, lets say the `tires` property of your `Car` object, first it checks if `Car` has that property itself. What that means is, is there a `tires` property directly attached to the `Car` object? Or in other words, is `Car` something like this:

```
{
    tires: 0,
    ...
}
```

And the answer is no.  You might think `Object.create()` does this, similar to what you might do in a constructor, i.e.

```
function Vehice(t) {
    this.tires = t;
    ...
};
var Car = new Vehicle(4);
```

All `Object.create()` does is make the object you pass in the `prototype` of the object it returns to you.

So after `Object.create()`, your object looks something like this

```
{
    __proto__: //reference to vehicle
}
```

So when it doesn't find `tires` directly attached to the object, it then looks at the prototype, in this case a reference to the `vehicle` object you created earlier.  The prototype (`vehicle`) **does** have the `tires` property, so it returns that value.

**Correction**

So what happens when you say `Car.tires = 6`?  When you **write** a value to an object property, things work differently.  <del>Javascript only looks to see if the object itself has that property to write to.</del> If the object itself doesn't have that property, it first checks down the prototype chain to make sure the property is not an inherited **readonly** property.  If it isn't, it **creates that property on the object itself** (so long as it's legal to write that property to the object).  So now you have something that looks like this:

```
{
    tires: 6,
    __proto__: //reference to vehicle
}
```

**End Correction**

Now when you read the `tires` property on the `Car` object, it first sees the `tires` property on the `Car` object itself and returns that value, never needing to look at the prototype.

This is why you can set the `tires` property on one vehicle and not effect the value of the others.

Now for the `seats.total` property.  When you read from the `seats` property, everything works as before.  There is no `seats` property on the `Car` object itself, so it looks to the prototype, which does have it.  Then it checks the object referred to by `seats` to see if it has a `total` property directly attached to it, and it does, so it just returns that value.

Now when you want to write to the `total` property, things are once again different.  The statement is this: `Car.seats.total = 4`.  What happens here is that you are setting the `total` property on the **object referenced by the `seats` property**.

Javascript first has to find the object referenced by `seats`.  It does this by checking to see if it is a property of the `Car` object itself.  It is not, so it checks the prototype, where it finds the `seats` property.  Now it can write the `total` property to the `seats` object as we saw before, but notice that this is happening to the `seats` property of the prototype, which is a referene to the `vehicle` object defined before and shared by `bike`.

In other words, javascript does not see that you are writing to a property of the `Car` object, so it doesn't create a `seats` property on the `Car` object and assign it a new object, and then a `total` property on that object and assign it `4`.

Now, when you try to read `bike`'s `seats` property, javascript first looks to see if `bike` has a `seats` property directly attached to it.  It does not, so it looks to `bike`'s prototype, which does have it and returns the modified `vehicle.seats` object.

I hope this clarifies what is happening and answers your questions.  Let me know if any part isn't clear, and I hope someone will correct me if I'm just plain wrong!

**Addendum:** I think coming from a traditional OO language the way it works for `tires` is what you would expect to happen:  You inherit the initial value, but if you change it, you don't expect it to change for every other instance of `vehicle`.

The way javascript does this is very space economical.  By only initially having the prototype have the property, if you have a thousand objects inheriting from `vehicle` and only 2 of them set the `tires` property, you've only used up space for three `Number`s instead of a thousand.

As for the way it works with `seats`, I suppose they could have designed the language to detect if you were setting a property on an inherited `object` (`seats`) and then copy the entire object into the instance.  My guess is that this would actually make the system less flexible and more complicated.  If you wanted `Car` to have it's own version of `seats`, you could specify it like so:

```
var car2 = Object.create(vehicle, {
    seats: {
        value: {
            count: vehicle.seats.total
        }
    }
});
```

or like so:

```
var car2 = Object.create(vehicle);
car2.seats = { count: vehicle.seats.total }; //create a new object like the one attached to vehicle
```

Does that last example make it clearer what's happening?

To me, in this case, an explicit constructor version of this would be more natural, but with javascript we can use constructors or `Object.create(), or various combinations of them to do what we need.

Ultimately though, Every set happens in two parts.  First, find the object we are setting the property on; Last, set the property. Everything before that final `.` is just there to do the first step:

`Car.seats.count = 10` means set the `count` property of the object referred to by `Car.seats` to 10.  What object is `Car.seats`? We are now following the rules of **reading** a property, not writing one.  `Car` doesn't have a `seats` property, so see if it inherits one.  If it doesn't, `Car.seats` will return `undefined`, and trying to set a property on `undefined` will throw an error.  If it does inherit it, `Car.seats` will return the object from somewhere down the prototype chain, in this case the object referred to by `vehicle`.  This object has a `count` property so just set it to 10.

`Car.tires = 4` means set the `tires` property of the object referred to by `Car` to 4. `Car` doesn't have a `tires` property, so make sure we are allowed to create one and then do so.

I hope this clarifies things.  Sorry for writing so much, but doing so has really helped solidify these concepts for me. Plus I learned some ECMAScript 5 stuff that i've been blissfully ignoring :-)