# How can i get rid of putting "new" before a function

Tags: javascript

I was wondering how can I make it posible to get rid of putting "new" before a function, for example:

```
new functionToDo("thingsToDo").iGotYouBruh("Halo Humans");
```

is there a posible way of doing this without the "new"?

here is the code I'm trying to use without the "new":

```
function local (title) {
    var storeTitle = title;
    this.addL = function(lString) {
        var storeText = lString;
        localStorage.setItem(storeTitle, storeText);
        console.info("Locally stored " + storeTitle.toUpperCase() + " with " + storeText.substring(0, 10) + "... As text.");
    };
    this.removeL = function() {
        localStorage.removeItem(storeTitle);
        console.info("Locally removed " + storeTitle + ".");
    };
    this.getL = function () {
        localStorage.getItem(storeTitle);
        console.info("Locally got string of " + storeTitle + ": " + localStorage.getItem(storeTitle));
    };
};
```

and here's what I would have to do to invoke the function:

```
new local("storedElement").getL();
```

Comment: I mean is it really that big of a deal?

Comment: I believe you're referring to [Object.create()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create)?

Comment: @self for me it was, now that it's solved I will make some research on the answer and learn from it.

Comment: @TimVermaelen Yes, I am refering to that and now I see there's already a post about this here [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2709612/using-object-create-instead-of-new)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is possible by checking whether `this` is an instance of the function itself and returning a new instance otherwise:

```
function local (title) {
    if (!(this instanceof local)) {
        return new local(title);
    }

    var storeTitle = title;
    this.addL = function(lString) {
        var storeText = lString;
        localStorage.setItem(storeTitle, storeText);
        console.info("Locally stored " + storeTitle.toUpperCase() + " with " + storeText.substring(0, 10) + "... As text.");
    };
    this.removeL = function() {
        localStorage.removeItem(storeTitle);
        console.info("Locally removed " + storeTitle + ".");
    };
    this.getL = function () {
        localStorage.getItem(storeTitle);
        console.info("Locally got string of " + storeTitle + ": " + localStorage.getItem(storeTitle));
    };
};
```

Comment: nice method. wasn't aware of that.

Answer (score 1):

You could use JavaScript closures. In particular look at the "Using Closures for the Module Pattern" section of [this webpage](http://www.joezimjs.com/javascript/javascript-closures-and-the-module-pattern/) for a full description. The idea is to have the function return an literal with all the required methods. Any functions or variables that you want to be kept private are just local variables for the function.

Comment: That helps but I don't get it, how would I make it work with only `local(title).getL()`? If you could explain it a bit you will be THE Master :)