# javascript prototype inheritance using constructor

Tags: javascript, inheritance, prototype

There are person class and student class. And student wants to inherit person property using only **prototype**. How i can use prototype to inherit fname, lname.

```
function Person(fname, lname){
  this.fname = fname;
  this.lname = lname 
}

function student(sid){
  this.sid = sid;
}

var s = new student("John","joy", 12);
console.log(s.name);
```

Comment: See the second part of the accepted answer to: [*What is the 'new' keyword in JavaScript?*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1646698/what-is-the-new-keyword-in-javascript/3658673#3658673). There are likely many, many duplicates of this question along the lines of "*How do I create a subclass?*", noting that ECMAScript doesn't have classes. There should be one that includes *Object.create()*, which is the ES5 way of doing things.

Comment: See [*Using “Object.create” instead of “new”*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2709612/using-object-create-instead-of-new) for the ES5 way of doing things.

Comment: "*How i can use prototype to inherit fname, lname.*" - you cannot. They're not prototype properties.