# Javascript Object prototype and Object.create method

Tags: javascript, oop, prototype

what is the difference between `Person.prototype` and `Object.create(Person.prototype)` ? Could I use each of them?

```
function Person(name) {
    this.name = name;
}  

Person.prototype.copy = function() {  
    return new this.constructor(this.name);
};  

// define the Student class  
function Student(name) {  
    Person.call(this, name);
}  

// inherit Person  
Student.prototype = Person.prototype;
//Student.prototype = Object.create(Person.prototype);
```

Comment: http://blog.slaks.net/2013-09-03/traditional-inheritance-in-javascript/

Comment: See also: [Using “Object.create” instead of “new”](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2709612/4639281)

Answer (score 6):

It is better to use  `Student.prototype = Object.create(Person.prototype)`  instead of `Student.prototype = Person.prototype;`

the reason being in the later case both prototype share a common object. So wen we add a new method in Student prototype , person prototype will also be accessed to that property. eg:-

```
Student.prototype = Person.prototype
Student.prototype.test = function(){ alert('in student');};
var person = new Person();
person.test();
```

this will alert 'in student'

Comment: To me with your code and  **Student.prototype = Object.create(Person.prototype)** also alerts to 'in student'. So they are sharing the same reference. So, what's the difference then?

Comment: Can you try this if you are getting the alert
function Student(){}
function Person(){}
Student.prototype = Object.create(Person.prototype);
Student.prototype.test = function(){ alert('in student');};
var person = new Person();
person.test();

Comment: @Olegalex: that is not possible, you can't just get the same result with and without Object.create.

Comment: @WiktorZychla I have the same result here with Firefox. Both variants alerts the student : `  function Person(name) {
  this.name = name;
}
Person.prototype.copy = function () {
  return new this.constructor(this.name);
};
// define the Student class  
function Student(name) {
  Person.call(this, name);
}
// inherit Person  

Student.prototype = Person.prototype;
//Student.prototype = Object.create(Person.prototype);
Student.prototype = Person.prototype
Student.prototype.test = function () {
  alert('in student');
};
var person = new Person();
person.test(); `

Comment: @Olegalex: you are not. Check this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/3rrct5rk/

Comment: @Olegalex: I believe you have an additional prototype reference copying just after Object.create. Basically then your both versions do the same. I removed this invalid line from the fiddle.

Comment: @WiktorZychla yes, that was the reason, a typo. Thanks!