# Javascript, instance property junk

Tags: javascript, object, prototype

In the Javascript code below I create 2 instances of Person (`p1` and `p2`).

When changing the name of `p1`, only the name of `p1` is changed (and not the name of `p2`). This is exactly what I expect.

But when changing `p1.sizes.width` and then checking the value of `p2.sizes.width`, it appears that `p1.sizes.width` is equal to `p2.sizes.width`.

Why?

```
var Person = {
  name: '',
  sizes: {width: {type:'size', value:undefined}, height: {type:'size', value:undefined}}
}

var p1 = Object.create(Person);
var p2 = Object.create(Person);

p1.name = "Alice";
p2.name = "Bob";

console.log(p1.name === "Alice") // true
console.log(p2.name === "Bob") // true

p1.sizes.width=20;

console.log(p1.sizes.width === 20) // true
console.log(p2.sizes.width === 20) // true (but I would had expected false...?!)
```

Answer (score 1):

You're creating a delegation chain to the same object as opposed to instantiating new versions of Person each time. This means that when the JIT compiler looks for the property sizes (which is undefined on the p1/p2 object) - it goes up to the next object in the delegation chain - in this case Person - so it will then modify .sizes.width. The reason why it doesn't matter on the names property is that you are overwriting that property on the individual instance. If you want separate instantiations then use the new keyword ie:

```
var Person = function(){
  this.name = '',
  this.sizes = {width: {type:'size', value:undefined}, height: {type:'size', value:undefined}}
}

var p1 = new Person();
var p2 = new Person();

p1.name = "Alice";
p2.name = "Bob";

console.log(p1.name === "Alice") // true
console.log(p2.name === "Bob") // true

p1.sizes.width=20;

console.log(p1.sizes.width === 20) // true
console.log(p2.sizes.width === 20) // false
```

You can read more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2709612/using-object-create-instead-of-new) and [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain)

Comment: Or you can do it with Object.create if you wish: var p1 = Object.create(Person.prototype);

Comment: Yes you can but not the way that OP is trying to do it

Answer (score 0):

Reading a property of any javascript object looks for the named property in the local properties of the object first. If not found searching proceeds to look at objects in the prototype chain one by one, looking for a property of the same name, until it finds one or the prototype chain has been exhausted. If found, the value of the property in the prototype chain is returned.

Writing a property of a javascript object always writes it as a local property - the value of a same named property in the prototype chain is not updated.

So...

Writing the unadorned property 'name' of an object returned by `Object.create(Person);` writes it in local properties, one value in `p1`, another in `p2`.

Writing to `p1.sizes.width=20;` however first needs to find a reference to object `p1.sizes`, by attempting to read it from `p1`. The read returns the `sizes` property of `Person`, found in the prototype chain, which is the same value for both `p1.sizes` and `p2.sizes`. Since they are the same object, writing to them is shared by `p1` and `p2`.

> **Reading properties - searches the prototype chain if needed.**
>
> **Writing properties - always writes to local properties.**