# Object.create() use

Tags: javascript, object, inheritance, prototype, prototypal-inheritance

I'm just learning about prototypal inheritance and am a little confused about the use of Object.create().  I'm confused about why Object.create() is needed in the following code:

```
function Mammal (name){
  this.name = name;
  this.offspring = [];
}

Mammal.prototype.haveBaby = function (){
  var baby = new Mammal('Baby ' + this.name);
  this.offspring.push(baby);
  return baby;
}

function Cat (name, color){
  Mammal.call(this, name);
  this.color = color;
}

Cat.prototype = Object.create(Mammal.prototype);
```

Does `function Cat(name, color){ Mammal.call(this, name) }` not pass the on the methods from Mammal? Is that why we need `Object.create()`?

Comment: No, calling the other constructor only runs the initialization code in that constructor. It does not affect the prototype chain. The technical reasons for preferring `Object.create()` to effect inheritance are pretty complicated; suffice to say that doing it that way is a Really Good Idea.

Comment: Not related to your question, but did you realise your cat objects produce non-cat offspring?

Answer (score 0):

`Object.create` was introduced with v1.8.5 as an [alternative way](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/whats-new-in-javascript-185--net-16779) to specify the prototype of an object. The actual difference in the above code is that it's a bit cleaner because the `Mammal` constructor isn't called redundantly when setting the prototype.

You can get the same output in the above pattern using the syntax:

```
Cat.prototype = new Mammal();
```

But here the `new` keyword will invoke the constructor redundantly, because

```
Mammal.call(this, name);
```

then explicitly invokes `Mammal` again with `this` set to the `Cat` instance. So that sets `name` and `offspring` on the `Cat` instance (not the prototype). It's a kind of super constructor pattern as per this [classical inheritance example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create).

The prototype chain makes `haveBaby()` available to all `Cat` instances and all `Mammal` instances. The only real difference is the intermediate `Mammal` instance vs empty object in that chain.

Comment: Redundantly? I would say *incorrectly*. `Object.create` is not just an alternative, it's the only way to do it right.

Comment: This debate may help clarify the implications... https://stackoverflow.com/a/12705137/1622684

Comment: @Bergi not disagreeing with you... the comments there contain most of the relevant issues. I didn't actually realise it was a strong point of contention.