# Object Create and new Object in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I want to create an array of objects and then build a JSON string. I have the following code. After trying many times, I found the solution. Can anybody explain the difference between create and the new operator? It looks to me create is making a copy of the object.

```
HmiUserList = [];
var oco = {};
//If I use the following line it gives wrong string
//oco = Object.create({});
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
//If I use the following gives right string
oco = new Object();
oco.UserName = i.toString();
oco.GroupName = (i + 2).toString();
var count = HmiUserList.push(oco);
console.log(JSON.stringify(HmiUserList));
}

//Wrong string if I use the create or if I don't use the new for oco
[{"UserName":"2","GroupName":"4"},{"UserName":"2","GroupName":"4"},{"UserName":"2","GroupName":"4"}]

//Target string [{"UserName":"0","GroupName":"2"},{"UserName":"1","GroupName":"3"},{"UserName":"2","GroupName":"4"}]
```

Comment: Likely a dup of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2709612/using-object-create-instead-of-new

Answer (score 1):

The difference in behaviour is here not related to using `Object.create` or `new`. It is caused by *where* you put the assignment to `oco`: in the loop or before the loop.

When you do it before the loop, there is only *one* object, which the loop keeps mutating, iteration after iteration, and it pushes that *same* object in the output array. Even though the array ends up with 3 object references, all three represent the *same* object.

When you do it *inside* the loop, you create a new object in each iteration, so that your property assignments affect *that* object, and not an object that was already pushed onto the array. Your array ends up with 3 different objects as intended.