# Javascript - HTML5 Audio bind event

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to bind an event where when the audio finished playing, it would fire a certain function, but however, when I bind the event it says aux.bind is not a function.

```
var aux = new Audio("file.mp3");
aux.bind("ended", function(e){
    aux.volume = 1.0;
});
```

I have even tried `aux.on(...)` and it does not work either.

**UPDATE**: *I will require to unbind the event later after the "ended" has fired*

Comment: Try [`onended()`](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/av_event_ended.asp)?

Comment: I think you may be trying to use jQuery's `bind()` function. Make sure you have included the jQuery library. If I'm not mistaken, the [plain JS `bind()` is different](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10115970/2397327). Therefore, try the `.onended()` event handler.

Comment: Can you explain the unbind part more? What's the reason to unbind the event?

Comment: @gothical the unbind is for to alter the volume, as the audio will be fired frequently, so that is why I would like to unbind the event later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the onended() event from the Audio object. Eg.

```
var aux = new Audio("file.mp3");
aud.play();
aud.onended = function() {
    alert("The audio has ended");
};
```

Comment: Thanks. I guess I can define `aux.onended = null` to make it stop listening :)