# Javascript function call within function

Tags: javascript

I am using VueJS with GoogleMaps to perform actions on a map. Therefore I wrote this function setup:

```
 methods: {

       // Init GIS
      init: function() {
         initGISMap(this.$els.map);
      },

       updateGIS: function() {
           getAutoCompletePlace(function(place){
               searchMarker.setPosition(place.geometry.location);
               autocompletePlace = place;

               if (place.geometry.viewport) {
                   map.fitBounds(place.geometry.viewport);
               } else {
                   map.setCenter(place.geometry.location);
                   map.setZoom(17);
               }

               self.updateIncidentForm();
           });
       },

      updateIncidentForm: function() {
          console.log("UpdateIncidentForm");
          getAddressComponents(function(components) {
              this.autoCompleteAddress = components;
              this.setIncidentAddressFields(components);
          });
      },
(...)
```

I want to call the `updateIncidentForm` function, when the `getAutocompletePlace` performs. The error I get in my console is:

> bundle.js:11073 Uncaught TypeError: self.updateIncidentForm is not a
>   function

Which is strange, as it is a function as defined in the code? Do I need to call the function differently?

Comment: where is your `var self`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are calling `self.updateIncidentForm()` in your callback function, but you don't actually define the variable `self` anywhere.

Presumably, you *meant* to write something like:

```
updateGIS: function() {
    var self = this;                       // <--- you forgot this line!
    getAutoCompletePlace(function(place){
        // (irrelevant code omitted)

        self.updateIncidentForm();
    });
},
```

The line `var self = this` saves a reference to the object you called the `updateGIS()` method on into the local variable `self`, so that you can use it inside the anonymous callback function you pass to `getAutoCompletePlace()` (where the value of `this` will be something different).

---

BTW, in modern (ES5.1+) JavaScript, another way to achieve the same result would be to use [`bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) to fix the value of `this` inside your callback, like this:

```
updateGIS: function() {
    getAutoCompletePlace(function(place){
        // (irrelevant code omitted)

        this.updateIncidentForm();
    }.bind(this));
},
```

The `.bind(this)` at the end of the callback function definition [locks the value of `this`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2236747/use-of-the-javascript-bind-method) inside the callback to the value it had in the outer `updateGIS()` function.