# JavaScript: How do I save data into a variable AFTER reading plain text from a local file?

Tags: javascript, file, bind, local, filereader

I've found many JavaScript tutorials on reading plain text from local files and on displaying that text onto a webpage element, but I cannot seem to find how to SAVE the data into an array that I can access from other parts of my script.

If I try to assign the text from the file to a global variable INSIDE the `FileReader.onload()` method, I can't access it OUTSIDE the method. Any advice?

The code below is for a school timetable project that I'm doing with my students that uses local files of courses, students, and teachers. I have a file input element defined as:

```
<input type="file" id="courseFile" onchange="School.addCourses(event);">
```

Then my School constructor includes the following arrays and methods:

```
function School (name) {
    this.courses = [];
    this.students = [];
    this.teachers = [];

    this.addCourses = function (event) {
        var fileInput = event.target;
        var r = new FileReader();
        r.readAsText(fileInput.files[0]);
        r.onload = function (e) {
            var text = r.result;
            var array = text.split("\n");
            document.getElementById("courseList").innerHTML = text;
            this.courses = array;
        }
    }
}
```

The text is loaded into `text` and then split into `array` and will even display on the page in the `courseList` element, but it does not copy the data into `this.courses`.

Comment: `this` inside the function is not the same as the `this` outside. You either have to use a global reference or use `bind` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2236747/use-of-the-javascript-bind-method

Comment: Sorry for my lack of understanding. By global reference, do you mean the solution offered by MISJHA below -- to use the literal object name, as in `School.course`? And I don't understand how to use the `bind()` method in this situation. Could you give me a little more instruction?

Comment: See http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LZZJzv

Comment: Thank you so much!! I still don't know if I really understand how the `bind()` method works, but you fixed my problem! Take the rest of the day off knowing you made someone else very happy!

Comment: Derek, what bind does is set a new value for the `this` variable inside the function. 
In general, an event handler will have `this` set to the object that triggered the event. So in your case, when you set `this.courses` inside the handler you were in fact creating a new object associated with the `this` which was the `input` object.

Using `bind()` , the `this` from the outer function is preserved.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is the scope of `this` inside `addCourses`.
to access the `function School` scope you need to change `this.courses = array` to `School.course = array`

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! Your advice works inside the onload() method -- if I add `alert(School.courses)` then it display the courses. But if I add `alert(this.courses)` outside the onload() method then it displays `undefined`.

Comment: please note that `this.courses` is a property of School, so anywhere you want to reference it inside `addCourses` you will have to use `School.courses`

Comment: What if I want to add other methods to the `School` class that can access the `courses` data? If I have to always refer to `School.courses`, doesn't that defeat the purpose of using objects? Perhaps the `bind` method suggested above might help?