# How can I call a class method inside a promise in Angular 2?

Tags: javascript, angular, promise

If I have an Angular 2 component and I get data from a service that returns an async promise or observable how can I then call a method in the component to display that data?

```
@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'charts',
  templateUrl: 'charts.component.html',
  providers: [DataService]
})
export class ChartsComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private dataService:DataService)

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getData();
  }

  getData(){
    this.dataService.getData().then(function (data) {
      this.drawChart(data);
    });
  }

  drawChart(){
     //implement drawing chart
  }
}
```

The problem is that inside a promise "this" in "this.drawChart()" no longer refers to the ChartsComponent class.  How can I call a class method post promise?

Also, I cant put drawChart() inside the promise because it needs to use other class properties.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

When you use [Arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions), the `this` is kept:

```
getData(){
  this.dataService.getData().then((data) => { // <-- changed here
    this.drawChart(data);
  });
}
```

Comment: Thank you! you saved me much head banging on a wall.

Comment: This works well, although leaves a syntax error in my IDE, time to upgrade tools.

Comment: @Paul Arrow functions are a new syntax, available at ES6 version of JS. Your IDE probably supports it, but it may require configuration.

Comment: @acdcjunior it appears this fails in IE11 - I initially tested in chrome

Comment: @Paul Yes, IE11 doesn't support it. You have to transpile it using babel or other. If you need it for IE11 and can't transpile, I suggest something like `this.dataService.getData().then(function (data) {    this.drawChart(data);
  }.bind(this));`

Answer (score 5):

There are 2 solutions:

1) using "self":

```
     var self = this;
     ngOnInit() {
        self.getData();
     }

     getData(){
        self.dataService.getData().then(function (data) {
        self.drawChart(data);
     });
```

}

2) using "bind method" (or something like that):

```
.then(function (data) {
        this.drawChart(data);
     }).bind(this)
```

you can find so much information about this method, for example: [Use of the JavaScript 'bind' method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2236747/use-of-the-javascript-bind-method)

I prefer first solution, because it helps make code more transparent.

Comment: Thanks, i am using the first solution.