# Why does javascript bind() not bind property by itself?

Tags: javascript, bind

I am trying to understand javascript `bind` method. I have read [this other SO post about bind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2236747/use-of-the-javascript-bind-method) method and learned a great deal. One of the posts linked to [javascripture](http://www.javascripture.com/Function#bind) where I played around with bind.

To my understanding, and according to [mozilla's site](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind), bind *"creates a new function that 'binds' `this` to the bound object."*

```
var Button = function(content) {  
  this.content = content; //stores content into this.content property
};

Button.prototype.click = function() { //adds click method
  console.log(this.content + ' clicked');
}

var myButton = new Button('OK');
console.log(myButton.content);        //OK
myButton.click();                     //OK clicked

var looseClick = myButton.click; 
console.log(looseClick.content);      //undefined
looseClick();                         //undefined clicked

var notLooseClick = myButton.click.bind(myButton);
console.log(notLooseClick.content);   //undefined
notLooseClick();                      //OK clicked
```

My confusion is the last var, `notLooseClick`. I don't understand why `notLooseClick.content` returns `undefined` while `notLooseClick();` returns `'OK clicked'`. I had expected `'OK'` to be bound to `notLooseClick.content.`

How can I bind `notLooseClick` so when I call `notLooseClick.content`, it is bound to Button's `this.content`, so when I type `notLooseClick.content` it returns `'OK'`? Why does `bind()` behave this way?

Comment: Unclear what you are asking. Your tests prove what `bind` does, that is, if you bind the function to the object it needs, you don't need to call it using `obj.func`, you can do `var func = obj.func.bind(obj);` and call `func()` and your `obj` will still be the `this` in that call.

Comment: Because in `notLooseClick.content` you're trying to get attribute `content` from function and not from `button`.

Comment: `content` is never going to be a property of the `function` it's a property of the `this` in the function

Comment: `content` stays a property of `myButton` (or `this`): `console.log(myButton.content);`. It does not become a property of `myButton.click`, `looseClick` or `notLooseClick`.

Answer (score 1):

You are misunderstanding what [`Function.bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) does. It makes sure that when a function is called, `this` will be whatever you pass in. It does not copy any properties of the object to the function that you've bound.

```
var Button = function(content) {  
  this.content = content; //stores content into this.content property
};

Button.prototype.click = function() { //adds click method
  console.log(this.content + ' clicked');
}

var okButton = new Button('OK');

// This calls click using okButton as its `this`
okButton.click();

var looseClick = okButton.click;
// This calls the same click function without specifying a `this`
// It will be window or null if on strict mode
looseClick();


// Here you are saying:
// No matter how this function is called, it will always use okButton as its `this`
var boundClick = okButton.click.bind(okButton);
boundClick();
```

You seem to be under the impression that the `bind` function would make your function inherit properties from the object that you bind it to. But that is not what it does, it binds the `this` within the call.

```
var notLooseClick = myButton.click.bind(myButton);
// It's undefined, you didn't copy properties of myButton to notLooseCLick
console.log(notLooseClick.content);   //undefined
// Here it works because you've set `this` in calls to notLooseClick to be myButton
notLooseClick();
```