# what does bind(this) means?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I already know that what bind do, it bound your given object or function to the function you want, but `bind(this)` is really confusing me.What does `this` in `bind` really means.

Below is the code from my react app with firebase Database.

```
componentWillMount: function() {
    this.firebaseRef = firebase.database().ref('todos');
    this.firebaseRef.limitToLast(25).on('value', function(dataSnapshot) {
      var items = [];
      dataSnapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
        var item = childSnapshot.val();
        item['key'] = childSnapshot.key;
        items.push(item);
      }.bind(this));

      this.setState({
        todos: items
      });
    }.bind(this));

  },
```

Comment: Do you know what `this` is? It's essentially a way to make sure the callback inherits the value of `this` from its surrounding scope.

Comment: Its same as `functionName.bind(context)`.  What its doing is setting setting context as component for `.on('value')`. So when you do `this.state....` this will point to correct scope

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use of the JavaScript 'bind' method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2236747/use-of-the-javascript-bind-method)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`bind(this)` here binds the context of your function inside `forEach()` to the scope of the componentWillMount().

`this` here refers to the the scope of `componentWillMount()`.

With `bind(this)`, `this` keyword inside the inner function will refer to the outer scope.
This is essential because in this case  `this.setState` inside the `forEach` function can be called as its scope is limited to `componentWillMount()`.

According to the **[docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind)**:

> The bind() method creates a new function that, when called, has its
>   this keyword set to the provided value, with a given sequence of
>   arguments preceding any provided when the new function is called.

Check out this demo which illustrates the usage of `bind(this)`.

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(){
    super();
    this.state = {
      data: [{
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 1,
    "title": "sunt aut facere repellat provident occaecati excepturi optio reprehenderit",
    "body": "quia et suscipit\nsuscipit recusandae consequuntur expedita et cum\nreprehenderit molestiae ut ut quas totam\nnostrum rerum est autem sunt rem eveniet architecto"
  }]  
    }
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    this.state.data.forEach(function(item) {
      console.log('outer scope ', this);
    }.bind(this))
     this.state.data.forEach(function(item) {
      console.log('Inner scope ', this);
    })
  }
  render() {
    return (
    <div>Hello</div>)
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.8/react.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.8/react-dom.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: can you demonstrate with a clean example of bind(this). Thanks

Comment: I added a demo to illustrate what I said.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't show full React component definition, but it most probably refers to React component instance where your `componentWillMount` is defined.

Answer (score 0):

You can play nice with `this` inside `forEach` - according to the https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach - instead of binding pass `this` as second argument for `forEach` statement.

```js
class App extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
      super();
      this.state = {
        data: [{
          "userId": 1,
          "id": 1,
          "title": "sunt aut facere repellat provident occaecati excepturi optio reprehenderit",
          "body": "quia et suscipit\nsuscipit recusandae consequuntur expedita et cum\nreprehenderit molestiae ut ut quas totam\nnostrum rerum est autem sunt rem eveniet architecto"
        }]
      }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
      this.state.data.forEach(function(item) {
        console.log('outer scope ', this);
      }, this) // be nice for context - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach
    }

    render() {
      return ( <div> Hello < /div>)
    }
}

ReactDOM.render( < App / > , document.getElementById('app'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.8/react.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.8/react-dom.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```