# What does `bind(this)` mean?

Tags: javascript, sapui5

In some part of `onInit` function of a controller in a `SAPUI5` application there is an auto generated code like this:

```
    this.getView().addEventDelegate({
            onBeforeFirstShow: function() {
                // Some codes
            }.bind(this)
        });
```

Now my question is what does `.bind(this)` mean? What does it do? Is it a pure JavaScript code or it is related to SAPUI5?

Comment: @Mahdi, next time, please search around a bit before asking.

Comment: **For UI5 developers:** it's important to note that `bind` returns a new function. This makes detaching the handler (e.g. in `onExit` | `exit`) more difficult. Your IDE should **not** suggest to use `bind`. Instead, pass the listener object as an argument if possible. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/61603539/5846045 or https://stackoverflow.com/a/61686925/5846045

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It binds the listener of the function to the current class, then when you use `this` pointer inside of the `onBeforeFirstShow` function, the `this` pointer refer to encapsulated class and you can access to its members.

Comment: This is because of bind(this). This allows to add new parameters. Please check the explanation here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10115970/1735425

Answer (score 13):

Yes, it's pure JavaScript code, you can learn more about what bind is and does [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind)

> The `bind()` method creates a new function that, when called, has its this keyword set to the provided value, with a given sequence of arguments preceding any provided when the new function is called.

In this case what it does is basically binding the current `this` to that function, so when `onBeforeFirstShow` is called, the `this` inside that function will be the one passed to the `bind` function.

You may also want to look at the new arrow function syntax in ES6, it auto binds the current `this` so `bind(this)` is not necessary.

Comment: So basically it is an extra step to tell the JS code where should the function context being set, correct? Then what would happen if there is no code to bind the current 'this' context?

Answer (score 1):

The `bind()` method creates a new function that, when called, has its this keyword set to the provided value, with a given sequence of arguments preceding any provided when the new function is called.

**Syntax**

> fun.bind(thisArg[, arg1[, arg2[, ...]]])

Reference to **[Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)**