# bind this is optional in class if no constructor?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have below class, but I'm confused by the bind this here. The class don't have a constructor and super(), why did he need to do bind this on setAll method? I removed the bind this, the application still work and no error.

```
class PushScheduleActions {

    /**
     * Request all API
     */
    fetchAll(params) {
        return dispatch => {
            dispatch(params);

            PushScheduleApi.getAll(params)
                .then(this.setAll.bind(this));//why use bind this here?
                .catch(this.setError.bind(this));
        }
    }

    setAll(data) {
        return data;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The class don't have a constructor and super()

That's completely irrelevant.

> why did he need to do bind this on setAll method?

The method only needs to be bound if

- it uses `this`and
- `this` should refer to what `this` refers to inside `fetchAll` (likely an instance of `PushScheduleActions`).

Since `setAll` doesn't reference `this`, there is no reason to bind.

**However**, the whole `setAll` method is unnecessary. The code would work exactly the same without `.then(this.setAll.bind(this))`. That makes me think that `PushScheduleActions` is supposed to be *subclassed* and child classes are supposed to overwrite `setAll`. Now, the child class' `setAll` might use `this` and expect it to refer to the instance. Since the parent class (`PushScheduleActions`) can't know that, binding the method is safer since it will ensure that child class implementations of `setAll` will work regardless if they use `this` or not.

Answer (score 1):

There is no relation between constructor, super and bind.

What bind does?
it returns a new function with the context user passed.

In your case, PushScheduleApi success case you are passing a new setAll function which is returned by bind method.

1. since your setAll function doesn't use context, you don't need to pass the    context.
2. dispatch is an arrow function, so context is inherited. So you dont need bind method. you can simply use this.setAll

Answer (score 0):

The **bind()** function creates a new bound function (BF). A BF is an exotic function object (a term from **ECMAScript 2015**) that wraps the original function object. Calling a BF generally, results in the execution of its wrapped function.

For more detail follow this link i hope it will help you a lot to understand to **bind()** method
[Use of the JavaScript 'bind' method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2236747/use-of-the-javascript-bind-method)

Comment: what is that needed? it worked without it in above case. I know what's the use of bind, I'm just asking why specifically why it's needed in my case.

Comment: In your case bind() method used to reuse methods and curry a function because bind() allows- set the value of "this" to an specific object. This becomes very helpful as sometimes "this" is not what is intended.