# Most performant pattern to bind "secondary" properties

Tags: javascript, node.js

Say we have this old-school JavaScript:

```
let obj = {
  foo: function(){
      // this === obj
  },
  bar: function(){
       // this === obj
  }
}
```

but if we want to attach some properties to foo and bar, like so:

```
obj.foo.x = function(){
     // this !== obj
}

obj.bar.y = function(){
     // this !== obj
}
```

what is the most performant pattern to use, to bind the "this" value within `obj.foo.x` and `obj.bar.y` to obj?

**Sometimes we can reference obj directly instead of using `this`. However, if obj is the prototype of another object, then referencing obj directly will not yield the correct result. I need to use the `this` value here (I think).**

In other words, this will not work:

```
obj.foo.x = function(){

}.bind(obj);

obj.bar.y = function(){

}.bind(obj);
```

Comment: [`Function.prototype.bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)

Comment: @str how can I use that here

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use of the JavaScript 'bind' method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2236747/use-of-the-javascript-bind-method)

Comment: I linked the documentation, I suggest to read it.

Comment: I have beening using JS for like 3 years, I know Function.prototype.bind :) I am not sure how to use it here. If it's obvious, then please add an answer, and I will upvote.

Comment: @str I updated the question, to demonstrate why Function.prototype.bind is not an obvious solution here.

Comment: Then I don't get your question. The code you added which "is not an obvious solution" adds the functions `x` to `obj.foo` and `y` to `obj.bar`. And both functions have `this` bound to `obj`. This is exactly what I thought is what is what you want.

Comment: To be very precise - obj will be used as the prototype of another object, bar. I cannot bind obj.foo.x to obj...it needs to be bound to bar. But I do not have a reference to bar when obj is created. See it?

Answer (score 0):

just use return this;

```
    let obj = {
  foo: function(){
      // this === obj
  },
  x: function(){
      // this === obj
  },
  bar: function(){
       // this === obj
    return this;
  }
}
```

than you can call `obj.bar().x();`

Comment: I don't want x to be a direct property of obj, I need x to be a "secondary" property of obj.