# bind() for binding to object

Tags: javascript, executioncontext

I'm binding the function `foo` to the object `myObject`.  I'm expecting the call to `foo` before I bind to log `global` to the console, and after the bind to log `myObject` to the console.

```js
var name = 'global';

function foo() {
  console.log(this.name);
}

var myObject = {
  name: 'myObject'
};

foo();
foo.bind(myObject);
foo();
```

The output is the global message in both instances though.

Comment: @le_m That's it!  Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use of the JavaScript 'bind' method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2236747/use-of-the-javascript-bind-method)

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan I don't think it's a duplicate.  I knew what the method does, just implemented it wrong.

Comment: But certainly the answer(s) to that question would answer this one?

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan Not really, I'd seen that question MDN and various blogs but didn't see what I was doing wrong.  What I needed was for someone to say "You've done that bit wrong."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`foo.bind()` returns a new function that has the binding, it doesn't modify the original function.

```js
var name = 'global';

function foo() {
  console.log(this.name);
}

var myObject = {
  name: 'myObject'
};

foo();
bar = foo.bind(myObject);
bar();
```