# Getting "setState is not a function" in React Native when attempting to fire a function from a listener

Tags: react-native

Im attempting to hide a logo on my app when the keyboard slides up. Unfortunately the Keyboard Avoiding View makes the logo look bad, so I rather just hide the logo entirely.

My current set up is this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
...
import {
    TextInput,
    Keyboard,
    ...
} from 'react-native';


class Login extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            ...,
            logoShow: true
        };
    }

    _keyboardDidShow () {
        this.setState({
            logoShow: false
        });
    }

    _keyboardDidHide () {
        this.setState({
            logoShow: true
        });
    }

    ...

    componentWillMount(){
        this.keyboardDidShowListener = Keyboard.addListener('keyboardDidShow', this._keyboardDidShow);
        this.keyboardDidHideListener = Keyboard.addListener('keyboardDidHide', this._keyboardDidHide);
    }

    componentWillUnmount () {
        this.keyboardDidShowListener.remove();
        this.keyboardDidHideListener.remove();
    }

    ...

    render() {
        ...
        <View>
            <TextInput style={...}
                       ...
                       onSubmitEditing={Keyboard.dismiss}

            />
        </View>
}
```

However in this set up, I get a red screen stating that "this.setState is not a function". I THINK this might be because Im attaching the function to the listener as this.setState works correctly in other places in this component, but I am unsure how to bubble up the returned state from the listener to the component's state.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to call `this.listener.bind(this)` or `s => this.listener(s)`

It's because JavaScript is passing `Keyboard` as `this` and `Keyboard` doesn't have a `_keyboardDidShow` method

Related: [How does the "this" keyword work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work)

Also related: [Use of the JavaScript 'bind' method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2236747/use-of-the-javascript-bind-method)

Comment: You're probably right, but I think you could put more effort into this answer, or better yet find one of the many duplicates.

Comment: fixed it for you :p

Answer (score 1):

You can define this function as an arrow function.
Eg -

_keyboardDidShow = () => {
        this.setState({
            logoShow: false
        });
    }