# React Typescript Infinite loop with render from function

Tags: reactjs, typescript, render

I've used a dynamic state to give each ListItem a separate state for the collapse to be open or not. However since I have to pass a parameter to the handleClick function, my render is going through an infinite loop.

The error that I get is

```
Lambdas are forbidden in JSX attributes due to their rendering performance impact
```

It doesn't allow me to use the Lambdas so I cannot do

```
<ListItem button={true} onClick={() => props.handleClick(index)}>
```

I was wondering if there was a way around this so I can have the handleClick for every list item with their index values and without it going through an infinite loop

**App.tsx**

```
interface IState {
error: any,
intro: any,
threads: any[],
title: any,
}

export default class App extends React.Component<{}, IState> {
    constructor (props : any) {
        super (props);

        this.state = {
            error: "",
            intro: "Welcome to RedQuick",
            threads: [],
            title: ""
        };

        this.getRedditPost = this.getRedditPost.bind(this)
        this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this)
    }

    public getRedditPost = async (e : any) => {
        e.preventDefault();

        const subreddit = e.target.elements.subreddit.value;
        const redditAPI = await fetch('https://www.reddit.com/r/'+ subreddit +'.json');
        const data = await redditAPI.json();

        console.log(data);

        if (data.kind) {
            this.setState({
                error: undefined,
                intro: undefined,
                threads: data.data.children,
                title: data.data.children[0].data.subreddit.toUpperCase()
            });
        } else {
            this.setState({
                error: "Please enter a valid subreddit name",
                intro: undefined,
                threads: [],
                title: undefined
            });
        }
    }

    public handleClick = (index : any)  => {
        this.setState({ [index]: true });
    }

    public render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Header 
                    getRedditPost={this.getRedditPost}
                />
                <p className="app__intro">{this.state.intro}</p>
                {
                    this.state.error === "" && this.state.title.length > 0 ?
                    <LinearProgress />:
                    <ThreadList 
                        error={this.state.error}
                        handleClick={this.handleClick}
                        threads={this.state.threads}
                        title={this.state.title}
                    />
                }   
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

**Threadlist.tsx**

```
<div className="threadlist__subreddit_threadlist">
    <List>
        { props.threads.map((thread : any, index : any) => 
            <div key={index} className="threadlist__subreddit_thread">
                <Divider />
                <ListItem button={true} onClick={props.handleClick(index)}/* component="a" href={thread.data.url}*/ >
                    <ListItemText primary={thread.data.title} secondary={<p><b>Author: </b>{thread.data.author}</p>} />
                    {props[index] ? <ExpandLess /> : <ExpandMore />}
                </ListItem>
                <Collapse in={props[index]} timeout="auto" unmountOnExit={true}>
                    <p>POOP</p>
                </Collapse>
                <Divider />
            </div>
        ) }
    </List> 
</div>
```

**ERROR:**

> Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component
>   repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or
>   componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to
>   prevent infinite loops.

Comment: issue is here: `onClick={props.handleClick(index)`, assign a fucntion  not value, like this: `onClick={() => props.handleClick(index)}` or use currying concept: `public handleClick = (index : any) = () => {
        this.setState({ [index]: true });
    }`

Comment: check this answer for more details. [Maximum update depth exceeded](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45124066/5185595)

Comment: Check [this](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/5591) issue and discussios.

Comment: If I try to assign a function, it gives me an error of saying "Lambdas are forbidden in JSX attributes due to their rendering performance impact"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use currying concept here, like this:

```
public handleClick = (index : any) = () => {
    this.setState({ [index]: true });
}
```

And use the handleClick in the same way: `onClick={props.handleClick(index)}`

Check this answer for more details: [What is 'Currying'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36314/what-is-currying)

Comment: Did you mean public handleClick = (index : any) => () => { ... } ?

Comment: Nope, thank you, it fixed the error but now there is another problem

Comment: share the issue, will find the solution for that also :)

Comment: So everything is working fine but the collapse is not working with the click, I've console.log(props[index]) inside ThreadList.tsx but first it comes out as undefined, maybe that is the issue?

Comment: its because you are not passing anything as index from parent in props, what the (expected) value you are assigning here: `in={props[index]}` ??

Comment: The index is coming from the map, so it should be fine?

Answer (score 0):

This issue is that `onClick` expects a function which can handle a parameter of `MouseEvent<T> | undefined`. However calling `onClick={handleClick(index)}` resolves to means that `handleClick(index)` is resolved on render and renders as `onClick={undefined}`.

You'd need to change your onClick handler to `onClick={() => handleClick(index))` or change handleClick to `handleClick = (index) => () => { ... }`.
}

The first option would flag the tslint `jsx-no-lambda` rule, in which case you'd need to go with the second option.

It might be worth considering disabling the `jsx-no-lamda` though, the purpose behind the rule is because of a potential performance impact as a new function  will be created with each render (discussed in [Why shouldn't JSX props use arrow functions or bind?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36677733/why-shouldnt-jsx-props-use-arrow-functions-or-bind)). However, it can make code more difficult to reason about. Generally it's considered bad to prematurely optimize code at the expense of readability.

If you later discover that an expensive render would benefit from this optimization you're much better off going with a readable solution such as memoizing it with a library such as [memobind](https://github.com/supnate/memobind)