# when binding onClick to button what does 'this' refer to

Tags: reactjs

I have the following code for reactjs:

```
 class Counter extends React.Component {
       constructor(props) {
          super(props);
          this.state = { count: 0};
       }

       incrementCount() {
          this.setState( {count: this.state.count + 1});
       }
       render() {
          return (
             <div> Count:{this.state.count}&nbsp;
                <button type="button" style={btnCSS}
                   **onClick={ this.incrementCount.bind(this) }>React</button>**
             </div>
          );
       }
    };
```

in the statement onClick={ this.incrementCount.bind(this) }>React does the first 'this' refer to the button and the second 'this' refer to the onClick event?

Comment: both refer to the `Counter` class

Comment: so that makes sense for the first 'this' as we need to get incrementCount but why the need to reference the class Counter again in the second 'this'  what else could possible be implied?

Comment: Are you familiar with how [`function.bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) works? This is a common pattern to ensure that class methods are called with the right context, even when passing them around as first-order objects

Comment: Specifically, it's there to make sure that `this.setState` and `this.state` within the `incrementCount` method still refer to the right instance of `Counter`

Comment: thanks, just learning.  this is really helpful

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/10115970/1810460 for more examples