# this.byId() returns undefined

Tags: sapui5

I have two functions in the controller, one of which is used for processing some event, let's say button click.

This one works fine:

```js
handleUploadPress: function(oEvent) {
   var oFileUploader = this.byId("streamerUploader");
   if (!oFileUploader.getValue()) {
    MessageToast.show("Choose file");
    return;
   }
```

And this one throws error:

```js
showResponse: function(id, response) {
    this.byId("streamerUploader").someMethod();
   }
```

In both functions "this" equals event provider, however, this.byId() returns undefined in the second one. What is the reason?

Comment: Where do you call the 'showResponse' method?

Comment: `this` should not be the event provider (i.e. the source of the event, like a button) but the controller. Only the controller (or more specific, the view object of the controller) has a `byId` method.

Comment: Could you add the code that binds these events? Excerpt from the XML view `<Button id="upload" press="handleUploadPress" text="{i18n>upload}"/>` or the JavaScript that attaches it `oFileUploader.attachUploadComplete(...)`. It's not possible to reliably answer your question without this.

Comment: I call the 'showResponse' method from js file used for control extension (contorls/FileUploader.js)

Comment: You should really specify more. Can you provide us with a code snippet of the custom control?

Comment: hm, maybe this is a pointer to controller. Alert of "this" shows "EventProvider my.app.controller.ControllerName". Nevetherless, it's the same in both methods

Comment: I've added the code of the extended control

Comment: Since you have no event for calling your custom function, how do you plan on calling the function? Like Florian said, providing a small part of your XML would help out a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*this* does not point to the controller when called from a callback method.

Your *handleUploadPress()* method, presumably, is an event handler and handles the press of a file upload button. The owner of this method is the controller, and calling *this.byId(...)* will behave as expected - it will return the component in the view with the specified ID.

However, in your callback method, *this* is not the controller. The method *this.byId* is undefined - it's a method defined by SAP UI5 controllers.

**What you need to do**

Before you send your request with *req.then(...)*, declare a variable whose value will be the *this* you will need to access, as such:

```
var that = this;
```

Then, to use the *byId* method, go by this variable.

```
that.byId(...).doSomeMethod();
```

I advise you read [this question and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback) to understand more about *this* in Javascript.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it's really helpful. I understand that "this" should point to different things in these methods, I just don't catch why alert of "this" in the second function shows that it is the same controller.

Comment: Isn't it also possible to use .bind(this)? It would be like req.then(function(response) {...}.bind(this)

Comment: @ChrisGabler well, not sure an alert is the best way to inspect an object. Put a breakpoint in both methods, then when stopped on each, have a look at each "this" object. Do they both appear to be identical?

Comment: @EricSchuster Although I'm not familiar with the bind() method, I don't see how it could work from inside the callback method. How would it link both "this" objects?

Comment: @ChrisNeve very naivly explained it enshures that the "this" from outside the brackets can be used inside the brackets. For the scientifically precise answer check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2236747/use-of-the-javascript-bind-method

Comment: @ChrisNeve I suspected this :D Via developer tools "this" in the first method points to the component and "this" in the second method points to... I don't know what, not the component for sure, it seems to be empty

Comment: @EricSchuster I think @ChrisNeve knows what bind does. But it's not clear how it can help in this context since we don't know how `showResponse` is called.