# Problem with Scope Functions in Method from Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, setinterval

I have a SetInterval inside to a Promise in Axios. When I try to execute a function in this SetInterval, I have the follow error:

```
    methods: {
    getJson() {
        axios.post(url, FormObject, config)
        .then(response => {
        var searchId = JSON.stringify(response.data.searchId)
        this.sendStatus(searchId)
        var status = setInterval(function(){ this.sendStatus(searchId) }, 
         30000);
        })
        .catch(err => (this.error = err))

      },

      sendStatus(searchId){},

     }
```

The first call (this.sendStatus(searchId)) working correctly. However, the setInterval return this error:

**Uncaught TypeError: this.sendStatus is not a function at eval**

Comment: I don't know vueJS, but your anonymous function is going to have a new value of `this` (which will almost certainly be the global object), hence the error. Use an arrow function instead of a `function() {..}` declaration (I see you use them elsewhere in this code) to keep the value of `this` the same as in the surrounding scope

Comment: have you tried using arrow function?

Comment: you must check what the "this" of ```this.sendStatus``` is referring to...try ```console.log(this)```

Comment: [How does the “this” keyword work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work).

Comment: I replace the function for an arrow function, and It work correctly! Thanks for your fast response!

Answer (score 3):

You are changing the context of `this` in your second call, as you are introducing a new function.

If you are using ES6, the easiest way to overcome this, is to use an arrow function instead of the function keyword.

```js
    var status = setInterval(() => { this.sendStatus(searchId) }, 
      30000);
    })
```

If you cannot use ES6, you have to use the `.bind()` function, which is explained in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2236747/use-of-the-javascript-bind-method) question. Easier, but dirtier would be to reassign `this` to a local variable.

`var that = this;`

Then use `that.sendStatus` in your callback function.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use an arrow function in your `setInterval`, like this :

```
setInterval(() => this.sendStatus(searchId))
```

Here is a [resource](https://hackernoon.com/javascript-es6-arrow-functions-and-lexical-this-f2a3e2a5e8c4) explaining more the arrow functions and `this`