# Calling a method of same service is not working inside jsPDF, Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, jspdf

Here is my `pdfService`, in Angular project looks below. When I call `this.formatter()` method inside myPDF is not working.

```
export class pdfService { 

    formatter(value: number): string {
        return new Intl.NumberFormat('en-IN', {style: 'decimal', currency: 'INR'}).format(value);
    }

    myPDF() {
        const doc = new jsPDF();
        doc.text('Values', 10, 25, 'left');
        doc.text(this.formatter(1000), 10, 25, 'left');
        doc.text(this.formatter(10000), 10, 35, 'left');

        window.open(doc.output('bloburl'));
    }

}
```

if I write method inside myPDF method, it works. below is code.

```
function formatter(value: number): string {
    return new Intl.NumberFormat('en-IN', {style: 'decimal', currency: 'INR'}).format(value);
}
```

I need to use `formatter` method in multiple PDF methods, so where do I write it?

Note: repeating `formatter` method in all PDF methods is one option but not the correct way.

Comment: you must miss something. There is no reason `doc.text(this.formatter(1000), 10, 25, 'left');` would not work whereas `doc.text(new Intl.NumberFormat('en-IN', {style: 'decimal', currency: 'INR'}).format(1000), 10, 25, 'left');` does work

Comment: How do you call myPDF? It needs to be called on the actual instance of `pdfService`, if you just got a pointer to the function and call it with no context, `this` will not be correctly bound.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might depend on the way you call your `myPDF` function, because that can affect how `this` inside the function will be bound. If you just have a reference to the function and call it without context, `this` will be undefined. You can circumvent that by binding your function reference to the actual instance - let me show you what I mean by some code:

```
export class MyClass {
  value = 5;

  func() {
    console.log(this.value);
  }
}


const instance = new MyClass();
instance.func(); // will work of course.

const referenceToFunc = instance.func;
referenceToFunc(); // will not work.

const boundReferenceToFunc = instance.func.bind(instance);
boundReferenceToFunc(); // will work, becuase reference has been bound to the instance.
```

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10115970/927511) explains it in greater detail.

Comment: I use typescript, Angular, could you convert your code to Typescript?

Comment: It is TypeScript, I thought it is pretty close to your example actually. Can you show how you call the function?