# Why do I need setTimeout.bind(window)

Tags: javascript

why do I need  setTimeout.bind(window) in javascript? I saw code pieces like this, why do I need this? I can use directly setTimeout.

```
setTimerFunctions: SetTimerFunctions = {
    setInterval: setInterval.bind(window),
    setTimeout: setTimeout.bind(window),
  }
```

Comment: Greetings and welcome to StackOverflow! With the niceties aside I have some bad news; we are not here to answer questions about technicalities; what we are here for is to help you to fix your code that is broken and provide an answer as to why the code you have does not work, we can't provide the "why does this do that", or "why do I need this", that's what Google is for :)

Comment: backwards compatibility, as some browsers didn't bind it for you, just like you _used_ to have to pass `console.log.bind(console)` instead of just `console.log` before they "stuck" the context for you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use of the JavaScript 'bind' method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2236747/use-of-the-javascript-bind-method)

Comment: @SamSwift웃 No, such questions are entirely on topic. This is _not_ a "debug my code for me" service.

Comment: @dandavis If you have an answer please post it as such

Answer (score 1):

## .bind

The first parameter for `bind` is the value of `this` inside the binded function. Passing `window` (or `null`, that would be equivalent) is a way to attach `this` to the global scope.

## setTimeout

`setTimeout` is a method of `window` (`window.setTimeout`), then `this` inside that function should be `window`, but it is not needed in current browsers.

Remember that `setTimeout(...)` is equivalent to call `window.setTimeout(...)` because `window` is the global context.

## Who is `this`?

An example:

```
var foobar = window.setTimeout;
```

This code could not work the way you would expect, it depends on the context, that we do not know.

For `window.setTimeout`, `this` would be the contextual `this` of this assignment. To force the reference to another `this`, you have to set the reference with `bind`:

```
var foobar = window.setTimeout.bind(window);
```

*Except* when assigning it from the global context, in that case the function will have `this` as `window`.

## Your code without binding

In your exact case, if you do do not bind and just assign:

```
setTimerFunctions: SetTimerFunctions = {
    setInterval: setInterval,
    setTimeout: setTimeout,
  }
```

then `this`, from the `setTimeout`/`setInterval` point of view, will be every instance of the class where this code is declared (as it seems to be part of a class declaration in TypeScript).

## Extra: function vs arrow function

Take a look at the documentation and differences between [`function`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/function) and [arrow functions `=>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions), this issue is one of the reasons why arrow functions were added.

Comment: you are right, then I do not have to use this way, I can use only ```setTimeout()```. I mean it is already bound, am I wrong?

Comment: Just doing `var foobar = window.setTimout;` will not work the way you could expect, because you referenced the function without a binded `this`, then `this` would be the context of that assignment, not necessarily the global/window scope, unless it is assigned there or statically binded.

Comment: you are right, if I want to assign setTimeout() into a property in an object, I should use .bind(window). Otherwise I could not call object's property somewhere else. I was looking if there was any other reason to use setTimeout like this. Because to assign setTimeout() in an object and call the object when you need does not make sense to me instead I can call directly setTimeout when I need. (by the way this is not my code, I am trying to understand for maintaining)

Comment: You are right, your code, without more context, does not seem to solve anything, just reference those global methods to internal methods.

Comment: it's just called an [_arrow function_](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions). "fat-arrow" comes from languages like CoffeeScript where arrow functions `x -> ...` are differentiated from fat arrows `x => ...`. JavaScript makes no such distinction.

Comment: @user633183 Thanks for the correction, I have edited the answer.

Answer (score 0):

When `method` is called on `obj`, the context (`this`) for `method` is bound to `obj`. This is known as a *dynamic call* because the context changes (is dynamic) based on the object calling the method -

```js
const obj = {
  method: function() {
    console.log('self?', this === obj)
    console.log('window?', this === window)
  }
}

obj.method() // <-- [obj] becomes [this] inside [method]
// self? true
// window? false
```

When a function is not called dynamically, it has *no context*, and instead `this` is bound to the global object, `window` -

```
const obj = {
  method: function() {
    console.log('self?', this === obj)
    console.log('window?', this === window)
  }
}

const fn = obj.method

fn() // <-- non-dynamic call, [this] binds to [window] as default context
// self? false
// window? true
```

---

To answer your question, in the case of `window.setTimeout`, binding doesn't really matter. Maybe `window` context was needed in the past, but it doesn't seem to be a requirement in modern browsers -

```js
const test = function() {
  console.log(this === window)
}

window.setTimeout(test, 1000) // true
window.setTimeout.bind(window)(test, 1000) // true
window.setTimeout.bind(null)(test, 1000) // true

setTimeout(test, 1000) // true
setTimeout.bind(window)(test, 1000) // true
setTimeout.bind(null)(test, 1000) // true
```

Binding of the "callback" *does* matter. Notice a `null` context binds `this` to the global object, `window` -

```js
const test = function () {
  console.log(this === window)
}

setTimeout(test, 1000) // true
setTimeout(test.bind(null), 1000) // true
setTimeout(test.bind({ a: 1 }), 1000) // false
```

Note however you cannot `bind` context of arrow functions; they always have a lexical `this` -

```js
const test = () => console.log(this === window)

setTimeout(test, 1000) // true
setTimeout(test.bind({ a: 1 }), 1000) // true
```