# Dynamic list not rendered

Tags: vue.js

I'm a beginner in VueJS so any help would be appreciated.

So I'm trying to display a list from my API. My API is working fine as I have tested it in Postman but when I try to create a list based on the response of my API, the list is not displayed. What am I doing wrong?

Here is my html:

```
<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
            <li v-for="user in users">
                {{ user.userid }}
            </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

And here is my js:

```
var tabs = new Vue({
        el: '#tabs',
        data: {
            users: []
        },
        mounted: function(){
            this.getAllUsers()
        },
        methods: {
            getAllUsers: function(){
                axios.get('<?php echo base_url(); ?>users/all_users')
                .then(function(response){
                    this.users = response.data
                    console.log(this.users)
                })
            }
        }
})
```

Here is the screenshot of the console, the data are just for testing.
[value of users after getting response from API](https://i.stack.imgur.com/76yQk.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your axios "then" method, you write:

```
.then(function(response){
  this.users = response.data;
});
```

When using `function` keyword to declare a function, it creates its own context and therefore `this` value of its parent scope is not passed down to the function.

In Vue's case, `this` in the child function is not the intended Vue instance.

To solve this, simply [pass the parent's `this` value to the callback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2236747/what-is-the-use-of-the-javascript-bind-method), or [use arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).

**Passing down using `.bind`**

```
.then(function(response){
  this.users = response.data;
}.bind(this));
```

**Using arrow function syntax**

```
.then(response => {
  this.users = response.data;
});
```

Comment: @Adrian Are you using PHP to embed javascript code right? then, I recommend you to use the `bind`, if you're not using a transpiler like Babel that code using array function won't work in all the browsers.  Just a headsup!

Comment: @FelipeGuizarDiaz Hi! No I'm not embedding javascript in PHP. Thanks for the headsup tho!

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php echo base_url(); ?>
```

I don't think this will be rendered in a js file. try hardcoding your baseURL instead.
Example:

```
getAllUsers: function(){
    axios.get('http://app.test/users/all_users') // or axios.get('/api/users/all_users') if you're using an api based route for your api
    .then(function(response) {
         this.users = response.data
         console.log(this.users)
    })
}
```

Comment: It is being rendered. I checked the script in elements and it showed the base URL.