# Class methods assigned to variable (alias) lose the value of this in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am having a problem understanding why the following does not work. I looked at the other suggested answers and none of them addresses this clearly in the context of a new class object.

Given the code below:

```js
class Example1 {
  constructor(v1) {
    this.v1 = v1;
  }

  method1() {
    console.log("v1 value = ",this.v1)
  }
}

const example1 = new Example1("value1");
const alias1 = example1.method1;

example1.method1();
alias1();
```

When I call `alias1()`, why is `this` `undefined`?

Comment: [How does the “this” keyword work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429)

Comment: Short answer, it depends on how you call it. Unless you use arrow function, where it becomes the outer function's `this`. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `this` refers to `method1` which does not have a `v1` ,

You can use [bind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2236747/what-is-the-use-of-the-javascript-bind-method) in the constructor :

> Bind creates a new function that will have `this` set to the first parameter passed to bind().

```js
class Example1 {
  constructor(v1) {
    this.v1 = v1;

    this.method1 = this.method1.bind(this);
  }

  method1() {
    console.log("v1 value = ", this.v1)
  }
}

const example1 = new Example1("value1");
const alias1 = example1.method1;

example1.method1();
alias1();
```

Comment: Thank you.  For the use case I asked this question for, this is my preferred solution.

Answer (score 5):

Its because the context of `this` changes when you call the `alias1` (method1) just as a regular function instead of calling it on object.

When you call it on the object then the context of `this` is that object and in your case that context is lost and is either `undefined` or it falls back to the context of the global object (`window` in browsers) depending on the [`strict mode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode)

You can set the context for `this` inside the alias using `bind` method to any object or you can define it inside some other object and that use that object to call it.

```js
class Example1 {
  constructor(v1) {
    this.v1 = v1;
  }

  method1() {
    console.log("v1 value = ", this.v1)
  }
}

const example1 = new Example1("value1");
example1.method1();

const alias = example1.method1;
const alias1 = alias.bind(example1);
alias1();

const example2 = {v1: 'foo', alias}
example2.alias();
```