# Vue.js v-if not re rendering

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have defined the following on my HTML:

```
<span v-if="valido" class="fas fa-check" style="position: absolute; right: 44px; top: 43px; color: green"></span>
<span v-else class="fas fa-exclamation-circle" style="position: absolute; right: 44px; top: 43px; color: red"></span>
```

Then I have this in my VM

```
data: {
    valido: false
}
```

And this function is being called when a input changes value

```
    validarRestricciones: function () {

        var empid = this.inputValue.substring(this.inputValue.indexOf('(') + 1, this.inputValue.length - 1);

        $.ajax({
            type: 'get',
            url: '/api/personas/validar?empid=' + empid,
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            dataType: "json",
            statusCode: {
                200: function (data) {
                    this.valido = true;
                    return true;
                },
                412: function (data) {
                    this.valido = false;
                    return false;
                },
                500: function (data) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Everything works fine and I can see in the console that `valido` changes from `false` to `true` but it does not change or redraw the spans that are attached to `valido` property. It seems that it is only done on the creation of the Vue component. How can I redraw that??.

Comment: try doing a binding of the context on the function for the status 200: function(data) { this.valido = true; return true; }.bind(this)

Comment: @KevinChacón that actually worked!!.. Don´t no why tho.. gonna google it

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2236747/what-is-the-use-of-the-javascript-bind-method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you sure it's actually changing the value of "valido" you set in the data property? At the beginning of the function try setting "this" to a variable, like "let vm = this", and then within the inner functions where you change "valido" call "vm.valido = false" for example.

It's possible "this.valido" is being assigned to the status code function immediately surrounding it rather than the one set in the data variable.