# JavaScript field access from anonymous function

Tags: javascript, class, anonymous-function

how can I access a fiel from within an anonymous function inside a method?
like in this example:

```
class Something {
    constructor (){
        this.gax = “gax”;
    }
    doSomething(){
        (function () {
           console.log(this.gax);
        }());
    }
}
new Something().doSomething();
```

this will result in an error that "this" is undefined.
thank you very much in advance, I could not find an answer in the web after searching for hours.
best,
lev

Comment: sorry but what you need the anonymous function for?

Comment: Probably relevent: [another SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2236747/what-is-the-use-of-the-javascript-bind-method)

Comment: ...or possibly [access correct 'this' in a callback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback) ...or about a half-dozen others, incl the one mentioned by @Dale.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your anonymous function, `this` is bound to the function; it no longer refers to the class.

Use an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) instead, which doesn't have it's own `this` binding.

```js
class Something {
    constructor (){
        this.gax = "gax";
    }
    doSomething(){
        (() => {
           console.log(this.gax);
        })();
    }
}
new Something().doSomething();
```

Alternatively, you could use something like `.call()`, `.apply()`, or `.bind()`:

```js
class Something {
    constructor (){
        this.gax = "gax";
    }
    doSomething(){
        (function() {
           console.log(this.gax);
        }).call(this);
    }
}
new Something().doSomething();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class Something {
    constructor (){
        this.gax = "gax";
    }
    doSomething(){
        (function () {
           console.log(this.gax);
        }).apply(this);
    }
}
new Something().doSomething();
```

You can use `apply` method. The `apply()` method calls a function with a given this value